# Get difference between two lists with Unique Entries

Tags: python, performance, list, set, set-difference

I have two lists in Python:

```
temp1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
temp2 = ['One', 'Two']
```

Assuming the elements in each list are unique, I want to create a third list with items from the first list which are not in the second list:

```
temp3 = ['Three', 'Four']
```

Are there any fast ways without cycles and checking?

Comment: Are the elements guaranteed unique? If you have `temp1 = ['One', 'One', 'One']` and `temp2 = ['One']`, do you want `['One', 'One']` back, or `[]`?

Comment: @michael-mrozek they are unique.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the order of the elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding elements not in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104305/finding-elements-not-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1789, accepted):

To get elements which are in `temp1` but not in `temp2` (*assuming uniqueness of the elements in each list*):

```
In [5]: list(set(temp1) - set(temp2))
Out[5]: ['Four', 'Three']
```

Beware that it is asymmetric :

```
In [5]: set([1, 2]) - set([2, 3])
Out[5]: set([1])
```

where you might expect/want it to equal `set([1, 3])`. If you do want `set([1, 3])` as your answer, you can use `set([1, 2]).symmetric_difference(set([2, 3]))`.

Comment: @Drewdin: Lists do not support the "-" operand. Sets, however, do, and that what is demonstrated above if you look closely.

Comment: thanks, i ended up using set(ListA).symmetric_difference(ListB)

Comment: symmetric difference can be written with: ^ (set1 ^ set2)

Comment: Why do I get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` when I perform this operation on `a = [1,2,2,2,3]` and `b = [2]`

Comment: Note that since sets are unordered, an iterator over the difference can return the elements in any order. E.g., `list(set(temp1) - set(temp2)) == ['Four', 'Three']` **or** `list(set(temp1) - set(temp2)) == ['Three', 'Four']`.

Comment: Order of input list is not preserved by this method.

Comment: Doesn't work (python 3.7):
a = [1,2,3,4,'5']
b = [1,2,3,4,'4']
list(set(a)-set(b))
['5']

Comment: what if there are duplicate elements? For example `a=[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], b=[1, 1, 2, 2]`

Comment: @Shark Deng, sets are collection of distinct objects by nature. If you want compare duplicates see matt b answer.

Comment: That solution WOULD NOT WORK in the case we have two equal elements in one list: 
Example:  
was [1,2,2], b was [1], expected [2,2]: [2] should equal [2, 2]

Comment: This no longer the preferred answer.  Tt is 10 years old, is for Python 2, and does not work in Python 3

Comment: Doesn't work, "list(set(servers) - set(verified_servers))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: scroll down for the XOR solution - works if you need to check the difference between both sets, not just "left - right"

Comment: Doesn't work if there are duplicate elements

Comment: what is the syntax 'In [5]: ' and 'Out[5]: ' ?

Answer (score 648):

The existing solutions all offer either one or the other of:

- Faster than O(n*m) performance.
- Preserve order of input list.

But so far no solution has both. If you want both, try this:

```
s = set(temp2)
temp3 = [x for x in temp1 if x not in s]
```

**Performance test**

```
import timeit
init = 'temp1 = list(range(100)); temp2 = [i * 2 for i in range(50)]'
print timeit.timeit('list(set(temp1) - set(temp2))', init, number = 100000)
print timeit.timeit('s = set(temp2);[x for x in temp1 if x not in s]', init, number = 100000)
print timeit.timeit('[item for item in temp1 if item not in temp2]', init, number = 100000)
```

Results:

```
4.34620224079 # ars' answer
4.2770634955  # This answer
30.7715615392 # matt b's answer
```

The method I presented as well as preserving order is also (slightly) faster than the set subtraction because it doesn't require construction of an unnecessary set. The performance difference would be more noticable if the first list is considerably longer than the second and if hashing is expensive. Here's a second test demonstrating this:

```
init = '''
temp1 = [str(i) for i in range(100000)]
temp2 = [str(i * 2) for i in range(50)]
'''
```

Results:

```
11.3836875916 # ars' answer
3.63890368748 # this answer (3 times faster!)
37.7445402279 # matt b's answer
```

Comment: Additional support for this answer: Ran across a use case where preserving list order was important for performance. When working with tarinfo or zipinfo objects I was using set subtraction. To exclude certain tarinfo objects from being extracted from the archive. Creating the new list was fast but super slow during extraction. The reason evaded me at first. Turns out reordering the tarinfo objects list caused a huge performance penalty. Switching to the list comprehension method saved the day.

Comment: @MarkByers - perhaps I should write an entirely new question for this. But how would this work in a forloop? For instance, if my temp1 and temp2 keep changing.. and I want to append the new information to temp3?

Comment: @MarkByers - sounds good. I'll keep thinking about it for a bit. but +1 for a great solution.

Comment: I agree with @Dejel
    >>> temp1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
    >>> temp2 = ['One', 'Two', 'Six']
    >>> s = set(temp2)
    >>> temp3 = [x for x in temp1 if x not in s]
    >>> temp3
    ['Three', 'Four']

Comment: Could you please explain why your code takes less time than that of [matt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3462164/2455888)? @MarkByers

Comment: @haccks Because checking membership of a list is an O(n) operation (iterating over the entire list), but checking membership of a set is O(1).

Comment: if you really need performance look at numpy version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31881491/2230844

Comment: I ran the above tests and for me [ar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists/3462160#3462160) and [SuperNova's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists/38240169#38240169) were better performing than this answer. Did anything change in the new python version? I'm using v3.7.3

Comment: This is still the fastest answer in v3.11. Note that denfromufa's answer using numpy is much much slower.

Answer (score 267):

Can be done using python XOR operator.

- This will remove the duplicates in each list
- This will show difference of temp1 from temp2 and temp2 from temp1.

---

```
set(temp1) ^ set(temp2)
```

Comment: Good find! I always overlooked this section of the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types.

Comment: This is the best for a 2-side difference

Comment: Definitely the best answer that addresses the OP's question directly "Get difference between two lists".  The others are too complicated with side cases.  And there is no datatype conversion.

Comment: does this perform better than any other solution w.r.t time?

Comment: how is this different than `set(temp1) - set(temp2)` ([ar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists/3462160#3462160)). I didn't find any difference in output when I ran this with `temp1` and `temp2`

Comment: @Gangula To see the difference between the two methods, add a value to `temp2` that is not present in `temp1` and try again.

Comment: @SuperNova new to Python here. How do you print out the differences found in set temp1 and also print out differences in set temp2? Meaning if I only wanted to see what was in temp1 and also print out another line of what only exists in temp2.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242887/how-to-xor-two-strings-in-python

Comment: @edjm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists-with-unique-entries/38240169#38240169 please check this

Answer (score 139):

You could use list comprehension:

```
temp3 = [item for item in temp1 if item not in temp2]
```

Comment: Turning `temp2` into a set before would make this a bit more efficient.

Comment: True, depends if Ockonal cares about duplicates or not (original question doesn't say)

Comment: Comment says the (lists|tuples) don't have duplicates.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I thought you were right about the duplicates at first. But `item not in temp2` and `item not in set(temp2)` will always return the same results, regardless if there are duplicates or not in `temp2`.

Comment: Up vote for not requiring list items to be hashable.

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
temp3 = set(temp1) - set(temp2)
```

Answer (score 29):

The difference between two lists (say list1 and list2) can be found using the following simple function.

```
def diff(list1, list2):
    c = set(list1).union(set(list2))  # or c = set(list1) | set(list2)
    d = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))  # or d = set(list1) & set(list2)
    return list(c - d)
```

or

```
def diff(list1, list2):
    return list(set(list1).symmetric_difference(set(list2)))  # or return list(set(list1) ^ set(list2))
```

By Using the above function, the difference can be found using `diff(temp2, temp1)` or `diff(temp1, temp2)`. Both will give the result `['Four', 'Three']`. You don't have to worry about the order of the list or which list is to be given first.

[Python doc reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)

Comment: Why not set(list1).symmetric_difference(set(list2))?

Answer (score 29):

In case you want the difference recursively, I have written a package for python:
https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff

### Installation

Install from PyPi:

```
pip install deepdiff
```

### Example usage

Importing

```
>>> from deepdiff import DeepDiff
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from __future__ import print_function # In case running on Python 2
```

Same object returns empty

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
>>> t2 = t1
>>> print(DeepDiff(t1, t2))
{}
```

Type of an item has changed

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:"2", 3:3}
>>> pprint(DeepDiff(t1, t2), indent=2)
{ 'type_changes': { 'root[2]': { 'newtype': <class 'str'>,
                                 'newvalue': '2',
                                 'oldtype': <class 'int'>,
                                 'oldvalue': 2}}}
```

Value of an item has changed

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:4, 3:3}
>>> pprint(DeepDiff(t1, t2), indent=2)
{'values_changed': {'root[2]': {'newvalue': 4, 'oldvalue': 2}}}
```

Item added and/or removed

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:4, 3:3, 5:5, 6:6}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff)
{'dic_item_added': ['root[5]', 'root[6]'],
 'dic_item_removed': ['root[4]'],
 'values_changed': {'root[2]': {'newvalue': 4, 'oldvalue': 2}}}
```

String difference

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":"world"}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:4, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":"world!"}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff, indent = 2)
{ 'values_changed': { 'root[2]': {'newvalue': 4, 'oldvalue': 2},
                      "root[4]['b']": { 'newvalue': 'world!',
                                        'oldvalue': 'world'}}}
```

String difference 2

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":"world!\nGoodbye!\n1\n2\nEnd"}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":"world\n1\n2\nEnd"}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff, indent = 2)
{ 'values_changed': { "root[4]['b']": { 'diff': '--- \n'
                                                '+++ \n'
                                                '@@ -1,5 +1,4 @@\n'
                                                '-world!\n'
                                                '-Goodbye!\n'
                                                '+world\n'
                                                ' 1\n'
                                                ' 2\n'
                                                ' End',
                                        'newvalue': 'world\n1\n2\nEnd',
                                        'oldvalue': 'world!\n'
                                                    'Goodbye!\n'
                                                    '1\n'
                                                    '2\n'
                                                    'End'}}}

>>> 
>>> print (ddiff['values_changed']["root[4]['b']"]["diff"])
--- 
+++ 
@@ -1,5 +1,4 @@
-world!
-Goodbye!
+world
 1
 2
 End
```

Type change

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, 3]}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":"world\n\n\nEnd"}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff, indent = 2)
{ 'type_changes': { "root[4]['b']": { 'newtype': <class 'str'>,
                                      'newvalue': 'world\n\n\nEnd',
                                      'oldtype': <class 'list'>,
                                      'oldvalue': [1, 2, 3]}}}
```

List difference

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, 3, 4]}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2]}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff, indent = 2)
{'iterable_item_removed': {"root[4]['b'][2]": 3, "root[4]['b'][3]": 4}}
```

List difference 2:

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, 3]}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 3, 2, 3]}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff, indent = 2)
{ 'iterable_item_added': {"root[4]['b'][3]": 3},
  'values_changed': { "root[4]['b'][1]": {'newvalue': 3, 'oldvalue': 2},
                      "root[4]['b'][2]": {'newvalue': 2, 'oldvalue': 3}}}
```

List difference ignoring order or duplicates: (with the same dictionaries as above)

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, 3]}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 3, 2, 3]}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2, ignore_order=True)
>>> print (ddiff)
{}
```

List that contains dictionary:

```
>>> t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, {1:1, 2:2}]}}
>>> t2 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:{"a":"hello", "b":[1, 2, {1:3}]}}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (ddiff, indent = 2)
{ 'dic_item_removed': ["root[4]['b'][2][2]"],
  'values_changed': {"root[4]['b'][2][1]": {'newvalue': 3, 'oldvalue': 1}}}
```

Sets:

```
>>> t1 = {1, 2, 8}
>>> t2 = {1, 2, 3, 5}
>>> ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
>>> pprint (DeepDiff(t1, t2))
{'set_item_added': ['root[3]', 'root[5]'], 'set_item_removed': ['root[8]']}
```

Named Tuples:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> t1 = Point(x=11, y=22)
>>> t2 = Point(x=11, y=23)
>>> pprint (DeepDiff(t1, t2))
{'values_changed': {'root.y': {'newvalue': 23, 'oldvalue': 22}}}
```

Custom objects:

```
>>> class ClassA(object):
...     a = 1
...     def __init__(self, b):
...         self.b = b
... 
>>> t1 = ClassA(1)
>>> t2 = ClassA(2)
>>> 
>>> pprint(DeepDiff(t1, t2))
{'values_changed': {'root.b': {'newvalue': 2, 'oldvalue': 1}}}
```

Object attribute added:

```
>>> t2.c = "new attribute"
>>> pprint(DeepDiff(t1, t2))
{'attribute_added': ['root.c'],
 'values_changed': {'root.b': {'newvalue': 2, 'oldvalue': 1}}}
```

Answer (score 25):

most simple way,

use **set().difference(set())**

```
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = [2,3]
print set(list_a).difference(set(list_b))
```

answer is `set([1])`

can print as a list,

```
print list(set(list_a).difference(set(list_b)))
```

Comment: removes dupllicates and doesn't preserve order

Answer (score 18):

i'll toss in since none of the present solutions yield a tuple:

```
temp3 = tuple(set(temp1) - set(temp2))
```

alternatively:

```
#edited using @Mark Byers idea. If you accept this one as answer, just accept his instead.
temp3 = tuple(x for x in temp1 if x not in set(temp2))
```

Like the other non-tuple yielding answers in this direction, it preserves order

Answer (score 17):

If you are really looking into performance, then use numpy!

Here is the full notebook as a gist on github with comparison between list, numpy, and pandas.

https://gist.github.com/denfromufa/2821ff59b02e9482be15d27f2bbd4451

[image]

Comment: i updated the notebook in the link and also the screenshot. Surprisingly pandas is slower than numpy even when switching to hashtable internally. Partly this maybe due to upcasting to int64.

Comment: running the tests from [Mark Byers Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists/3462202#3462202), numpy took the longest of all answers (ars, SuperNova, Mark Byers, Matt b).

Answer (score 16):

I wanted something that would take two lists and could do what `diff` in `bash` does. Since this question pops up first when you search for "python diff two lists" and is not very specific, I will post what I came up with.

Using [`SequenceMather`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) from `difflib` you can compare two lists like `diff` does. None of the other answers will tell you the position where the difference occurs, but this one does. Some answers give the difference in only one direction. Some reorder the elements. Some don't handle duplicates. But this solution gives you a true difference between two lists:

```
a = 'A quick fox jumps the lazy dog'.split()
b = 'A quick brown mouse jumps over the dog'.split()

from difflib import SequenceMatcher

for tag, i, j, k, l in SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).get_opcodes():
  if tag == 'equal': print('both have', a[i:j])
  if tag in ('delete', 'replace'): print('  1st has', a[i:j])
  if tag in ('insert', 'replace'): print('  2nd has', b[k:l])
```

This outputs:

```
both have ['A', 'quick']
  1st has ['fox']
  2nd has ['brown', 'mouse']
both have ['jumps']
  2nd has ['over']
both have ['the']
  1st has ['lazy']
both have ['dog']
```

Of course, if your application makes the same assumptions the other answers make, you will benefit from them the most. But if you are looking for a true `diff` functionality, then this is the only way to go.

For example, none of the other answers could handle:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [5,4,3,2,1]
```

But this one does:

```
  2nd has [5, 4, 3, 2]
both have [1]
  1st has [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's a `Counter` answer for the simplest case.

This is shorter than the one above that does two-way diffs because it only does exactly what the question asks: generate a list of what's in the first list but not the second.

```
from collections import Counter

lst1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
lst2 = ['One', 'Two']

c1 = Counter(lst1)
c2 = Counter(lst2)
diff = list((c1 - c2).elements())
```

Alternatively, depending on your readability preferences, it makes for a decent one-liner:

```
diff = list((Counter(lst1) - Counter(lst2)).elements())
```

Output:

```
['Three', 'Four']
```

*Note that you can remove the `list(...)` call if you are just iterating over it.*

Because this solution uses counters, it handles quantities properly vs the many set-based answers.  For example on this input:

```
lst1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Two', 'Two', 'Three', 'Three', 'Four']
lst2 = ['One', 'Two']
```

The output is:

```
['Two', 'Two', 'Three', 'Three', 'Four']
```

Comment: Good job! This is the right, general answer.

Answer (score 12):

this could be even faster than Mark's list comprehension:

```
list(itertools.filterfalse(set(temp2).__contains__, temp1))
```

Comment: Might want to include the `from itertools import filterfalse` bit here. Also note that this doesn't return a sequence like the others, it returns an iterator.

Answer (score 7):

single line version of **arulmr** solution

```
def diff(listA, listB):
    return set(listA) - set(listB) | set(listB) -set(listA)
```

Comment: This makes no sense and is very unclear. Is it `(set(a) - set(b)) | (set(a) - set(b))` (union of a difference with itself?) or `set(a) - (set(b) | set(a)) - set(b)` (which would subtract the whole set `a` from itself, always leading to an empty result)?. I can tell you that it is the first one, because of operator precedence, but still, the union and the repetition here is useless.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a modified version of @SuperNova's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38240169/11430726)

```
def get_diff(a: list, b: list) -> list:
    return list(set(a) ^ set(b))
```

Answer (score 6):

This is another solution:

```
def diff(a, b):
    xa = [i for i in set(a) if i not in b]
    xb = [i for i in set(b) if i not in a]
    return xa + xb
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's say we have two lists

```
list1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

we can see from the above two lists that items 1, 3, 5 exist in list2 and items 7, 9 do not. On the other hand, items 1, 3, 5 exist in list1 and items 2, 4 do not.

What is the best solution to return a new list containing items 7, 9 and 2, 4?

All answers above find the solution, now whats the most optimal?

```
def difference(list1, list2):
    new_list = []
    for i in list1:
        if i not in list2:
            new_list.append(i)

    for j in list2:
        if j not in list1:
            new_list.append(j)
    return new_list
```

versus

```
def sym_diff(list1, list2):
    return list(set(list1).symmetric_difference(set(list2)))
```

Using timeit we can see the results

```
t1 = timeit.Timer("difference(list1, list2)", "from __main__ import difference, 
list1, list2")
t2 = timeit.Timer("sym_diff(list1, list2)", "from __main__ import sym_diff, 
list1, list2")

print('Using two for loops', t1.timeit(number=100000), 'Milliseconds')
print('Using two for loops', t2.timeit(number=100000), 'Milliseconds')
```

returns

```
[7, 9, 2, 4]
Using two for loops 0.11572412995155901 Milliseconds
Using symmetric_difference 0.11285737506113946 Milliseconds

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 6):

If you should remove all values from list **a**, which are present in list **b**.

```
def list_diff(a, b):
    r = []

    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            r.append(i)
    return r
```

list_diff([1,2,2], [1])

Result: [2,2]

**or**

```
def list_diff(a, b):
    return [x for x in a if x not in b]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a naive method if the elements of the difflist are sorted and sets.

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list2=[1,2,3]

print list1[len(list2):]
```

or with native set methods:

```
subset=set(list1).difference(list2)

print subset

import timeit
init = 'temp1 = list(range(100)); temp2 = [i * 2 for i in range(50)]'
print "Naive solution: ", timeit.timeit('temp1[len(temp2):]', init, number = 100000)
print "Native set solution: ", timeit.timeit('set(temp1).difference(temp2)', init, number = 100000)
```

Naive solution:  0.0787101593292

Native set solution:  0.998837615564

Answer (score 5):

If you run into `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` you need to turn lists or sets into tuples, e.g.

```
set(map(tuple, list_of_lists1)).symmetric_difference(set(map(tuple, list_of_lists2)))
```

See also [How to compare a list of lists/sets in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105777/how-to-compare-a-list-of-lists-sets-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

I am little too late in the game for this but you can do a comparison of performance of some of the above mentioned code with this, two of the fastest contenders are,

```
list(set(x).symmetric_difference(set(y)))
list(set(x) ^ set(y))
```

I apologize for the elementary level of coding.

```
import time
import random
from itertools import filterfalse

# 1 - performance (time taken)
# 2 - correctness (answer - 1,4,5,6)
# set performance
performance = 1
numberoftests = 7

def answer(x,y,z):
    if z == 0:
        start = time.clock()
        lists = (str(list(set(x)-set(y))+list(set(y)-set(y))))
        times = ("1 = " + str(time.clock() - start))
        return (lists,times)

    elif z == 1:
        start = time.clock()
        lists = (str(list(set(x).symmetric_difference(set(y)))))
        times = ("2 = " + str(time.clock() - start))
        return (lists,times)

    elif z == 2:
        start = time.clock()
        lists = (str(list(set(x) ^ set(y))))
        times = ("3 = " + str(time.clock() - start))
        return (lists,times)

    elif z == 3:
        start = time.clock()
        lists = (filterfalse(set(y).__contains__, x))
        times = ("4 = " + str(time.clock() - start))
        return (lists,times)

    elif z == 4:
        start = time.clock()
        lists = (tuple(set(x) - set(y)))
        times = ("5 = " + str(time.clock() - start))
        return (lists,times)

    elif z == 5:
        start = time.clock()
        lists = ([tt for tt in x if tt not in y])
        times = ("6 = " + str(time.clock() - start))
        return (lists,times)

    else:    
        start = time.clock()
        Xarray = [iDa for iDa in x if iDa not in y]
        Yarray = [iDb for iDb in y if iDb not in x]
        lists = (str(Xarray + Yarray))
        times = ("7 = " + str(time.clock() - start))
        return (lists,times)

n = numberoftests

if performance == 2:
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    b = [3,2,6]
    for c in range(0,n):
        d = answer(a,b,c)
        print(d[0])

elif performance == 1:
    for tests in range(0,10):
        print("Test Number" + str(tests + 1))
        a = random.sample(range(1, 900000), 9999)
        b = random.sample(range(1, 900000), 9999)
        for c in range(0,n):
            #if c not in (1,4,5,6):
            d = answer(a,b,c)
            print(d[1])
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few simple, ***order-preserving*** ways of diffing two lists of strings.

**Code**

An unusual approach using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib):

```
import pathlib


temp1 = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
temp2 = ["One", "Two"]

p = pathlib.Path(*temp1)
r = p.relative_to(*temp2)
list(r.parts)
# ['Three', 'Four']
```

This assumes both lists contain strings with equivalent beginnings.  See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to) for more details.  Note, it is not particularly fast compared to set operations.

---

A straight-forward implementation using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
import itertools as it


[x for x, y in it.zip_longest(temp1, temp2) if x != y]
# ['Three', 'Four']
```

Comment: The itertools solution only works when the elements in `temp1` and `temp2` line up well. If you, for example, turn around the elements in `temp2` or insert some other value in the beginning of `temp2`, the listcomp will just return the same elements as in `temp1`

Comment: Yes,  it is a feature of these approaches.  As mentioned, these solutions are order preserving - they assume some relative order between the lists.  An unordered solution would be to diff two sets.

Comment: "This assumes both lists contain strings with equivalent beginnings". If you assume this, all you need to do is truncate the longest list with the length of the shortest; you don’t need `pathlib` or any module.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use converting to sets and then using the "difference()" function. The full code is :

```
temp1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'  ]                   
temp2 = ['One', 'Two']
set1 = set(temp1)
set2 = set(temp2)
set3 = set1.difference(set2)
temp3 = list(set3)
print(temp3)
```

Output:

```
>>>print(temp3)
['Three', 'Four']
```

It's the easiest to undersand, and morover in future if you work with large data, converting it to sets will remove duplicates if duplicates are not required. Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: The difference function is the same as the - operator shown in the accepted answer, so not sure this really adds any new information 10 years later

Answer (score 5):

I know this question got great answers already but I wish to add the following method using `numpy`.

```
temp1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
temp2 = ['One', 'Two']

list(np.setdiff1d(temp1,temp2))

['Four', 'Three'] #Output
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want something more like a changeset... could use Counter

```
from collections import Counter

def diff(a, b):
  """ more verbose than needs to be, for clarity """
  ca, cb = Counter(a), Counter(b)
  to_add = cb - ca
  to_remove = ca - cb
  changes = Counter(to_add)
  changes.subtract(to_remove)
  return changes

lista = ['one', 'three', 'four', 'four', 'one']
listb = ['one', 'two', 'three']

In [127]: diff(lista, listb)
Out[127]: Counter({'two': 1, 'one': -1, 'four': -2})
# in order to go from lista to list b, you need to add a "two", remove a "one", and remove two "four"s

In [128]: diff(listb, lista)
Out[128]: Counter({'four': 2, 'one': 1, 'two': -1})
# in order to go from listb to lista, you must add two "four"s, add a "one", and remove a "two"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can calculate intersection minus union of lists:

```
temp1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
temp2 = ['One', 'Two', 'Five']

set(temp1+temp2)-(set(temp1)&set(temp2))

Out: set(['Four', 'Five', 'Three'])
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with one line.
The question is given two lists (temp1 and temp2) return their difference in a third list (temp3).

```
temp3 = list(set(temp1).difference(set(temp2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an simple way to distinguish two lists (whatever the contents are), you can get the result as shown below :

```
>>> from sets import Set
>>>
>>> l1 = ['xvda', False, 'xvdbb', 12, 'xvdbc']
>>> l2 = ['xvda', 'xvdbb', 'xvdbc', 'xvdbd', None]
>>>
>>> Set(l1).symmetric_difference(Set(l2))
Set([False, 'xvdbd', None, 12])
```

Hope this will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can cycle through the first list and, for every item that isn't in the second list but is in the first list, add it to the third list. E.g:

```
temp3 = []
for i in temp1:
    if i not in temp2:
        temp3.append(i)
print(temp3)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the lists are of objects and not primitive types, this is one way of doing it.

The code is more explicit and gives out a copy.
This may not be an efficient implementation, but clean for smaller lists of objects.

```
a = [
    {'id1': 1, 'id2': 'A'},
    {'id1': 1, 'id2': 'B'},
    {'id1': 1, 'id2': 'C'},  # out
    {'id1': 2, 'id2': 'A'},
    {'id1': 2, 'id2': 'B'},  # out
]
b = [
    {'id1': 1, 'id2': 'A'},
    {'id1': 1, 'id2': 'B'},
    {'id1': 2, 'id2': 'A'},
]


def difference(a, b):
  for x in a:
    for y in b:
      if x['id1'] == y['id1'] and x['id2'] == y['id2']:
        x['is_removed'] = True

  c = [x for x in a if not x.get('is_removed', False)]
  return c


print(difference(a, b))
```

Answer (score -1):

Out of all possible option fastest option is:

```
s = set(temp2);
[x for x in temp1 if x not in s]
```

**Performance results**

```js
    import timeit
    init = 'temp1 = list(range(100)); temp2 = [i * 2 for i in range(50)]'
    print(timeit.timeit('list(set(temp1) - set(temp2))', init, number = 100000))
    print(timeit.timeit('s = set(temp2);[x for x in temp1 if x not in s]', init, number = 100000))
    print(timeit.timeit('[item for item in temp1 if item not in temp2]', init, number = 100000))
    print(timeit.timeit('list(set(temp1) ^ set(temp2))', init, number = 100000))
```

**Results**

```
0.3485999000258744
0.3314229999668896
2.067719299986493
0.3791518000070937
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def diffList(list1, list2):     # returns the difference between two lists.
    if len(list1) > len(list2):
        return (list(set(list1) - set(list2)))
    else:
        return (list(set(list2) - set(list1)))
```

e.g. if `list1 = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]` and `list2 = [25, 40, 35]` then the returned list will be `output = [10, 20, 30, 15]`

Comment: You can not do like this for difference operation.
Even in case of integers, if you tell a function to perform 'a - b', it is supposed to subtract 'b' from 'a' only, no matter if 'b' is larger than 'a' or otherwise.

Similar is the case with list and sets. A - B and B - A both can be valid operations irrespective of the lengths of A and B, you just need to exclude the contents of B from A to perform A - B.

Answer (score -3):

Following on @arkolec's answer, here is a utility class for comparing lists, tuples and sets:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

class ListDiffer:

    def __init__(self, left, right, strict:bool=False):
        assert isinstance(left, (list, tuple, set)), "left must be list, tuple or set"
        assert isinstance(right, (list, tuple, set)), "right must be list, tuple or set"
        self.l = list(left) if isinstance(left, (tuple, set)) else left
        self.r = list(right) if isinstance(left, (tuple, set)) else right

        if strict:
            assert isinstance(left, right.__class__), \
                f'left type ({left.__class__.__name__}) must equal right type ({right.__class__.__name__})'

        self.diffs = []
        self.equal = []

        for tag, i, j, k, l in SequenceMatcher(None, self.l, self.r).get_opcodes():
            if tag in ['delete', 'replace', 'insert']:
                self.diffs.append((tag, i, j, k, l))
            elif tag == 'equal':
                [self.equal.append(v) for v in left[i:j]]
                


    def has_diffs(self):
        return len(self.diffs) > 0


    def only_left(self):
        a = self.l[:]
        [a.remove(v) for v in self.equal]
        return a

    def only_right(self):
        a = self.r[:]
        [a.remove(v) for v in self.equal]
        return a


    def __str__(self, verbose:bool=False):
        iD = 0
        sb = []
        if verbose:
            sb.append(f"left: {self.l}\n")
            sb.append(f"right: {self.r}\n")
            sb.append(f"diffs: ")
        for tag, i, j, k, l in self.diffs:
            s = f"({iD})"
            if iD > 0: sb.append(' | ')
            if tag in ('delete', 'replace'): s = f'{s} l:{self.l[i:j]}'
            if tag in ('insert', 'replace'): s = f'{s} r:{self.r[k:l]}'
            sb.append(s)
            iD = iD + 1

        if verbose:
            sb.append(f"\nequal: {self.equal}")
        return ''.join(sb)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return "<ListDiffer> {}".format(self.__str__())
```

Usage:

```
left = ['a','b','c']
right = ['aa','b','c','d']
# right = ('aa','b','c','d')
ld = ListDiffer(left, right, strict=True)
print(f'ld.has_diffs(): {ld.has_diffs()}')
print(f'ld: {ld}')
print(f'ld.only_left(): {ld.only_left()}')
print(f'ld.only_right(): {ld.only_right()}')
```

Output:

```
ld.has_diffs(): True
ld: (0) l:['a'] r:['aa'] | (1) r:['d']
ld.only_left(): ['a']
ld.only_right(): ['aa', 'd']
```

I cannot speak to performance but you could use `ld.only_left()` to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Why the heavy downvotes?