# Is there a more pythonic way to populate a this list?

Tags: python, list

I want to clean the strings from a django query so it can be used in latex

```
items = []
items_to_clean = items.objects.get.all().values()
for dic in items_to_clean:
    items.append(dicttolatex(dic))
```

This is my standard aproach to this task. Can this somehow be solved whith list comprehension. since `dicttolatex` is a function returning a dict.

Comment: It isn't clear how `dicttolatex` being  a `dict` prevents you from using a list comprehension instead of your "standard approach".

Comment: If you have `items = []`, what's `items.objects`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid repeated calls to `append` by using a list comprehension:

```
items = [dicttolatex(dic) for dic in items_to_clean]
```

Comment: Oh I had it all mixed up - `items = [dict for dictolatex(item) for item in items_to_clean]` - thanks for writing it out for me

Answer (score 5):

You could do use [map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function-python) why rediscover the wheel

**Sample:**

```
lst=[1,2,3,4]
def add(n):
    return n+n

a=[]
a.extend( map(add,lst))
print a
```

**output:**

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

That is in your case :

```
items_to_clean = items.objects.get.all().values()
items = map(dicttolatex,items_to_clean)
```

Comment: this looks nice too, but I'll stick with juanchopanzas method since it creates the list and the values in one line of code

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer `map` also creates the list with the values in only one line. It's even shorter... `items = map(dicttolatex, items_to_clean)`

Comment: @MaximilianKindshofer If you're making a list, it is pretty much a matter of opinion which one is preferable. The generator expression used in the list comprehension can be used in different contexts when you don't necessarily need to build a list. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map. Personally, I am used to list comprehensions and use them all the time, but map still seems easier to read, and easier to search for in source code.