# How to remove quotes from a single value in a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list as :

```
a=[u'hello',u'well',u'1024']
```

I want to have it as :

```
a=[u'hello',u'well',1024]
```

So please suggest how will  i have it.

Comment: Is all values where you want to *remove the quotes* , just normal numbers? or decimals?

Comment: `int(a[2])` what have you tried? if you've defined the list like that then just remove the characters that make it a string...

Comment: None of those values have quotes in them, unless you're referring to values in the Python syntax tree.

Comment: You might want to chek if the string represents an int. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/python-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except, The code from this answer can be modified to check for floats as well. When you are sure the string can be converted, convert it to int (or float)

Answer (score 1):

Python [Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function-python) and  a conversion function with try catch  will do

```
lst=[u'hello',u'well',u'1024']

def conversion(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except Exception:
        return value


map(conversion,lst)
[u'hello', u'well', 1024]
```

Comment: A bare `except` catches all sort of thing you don't want to catch (`KeyboardInterrupt`, `MemoryError`, ...). `except Exception:` is a better alternative.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Better yet, `ValueError`.

Comment: You can never really be sure, can you? :) `int(None)` raises `TypeError`.

Comment: Could the down voter enlighten me  why this is wrong