# Python 2.7 Value Error math domain error

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, simplecv

> UPDATE

@peter wood comment is actually answer but it is comment so i just upvoted it.

The accepted answer reveals the presence of negative number in the matrix. 
What I have done is converted both image to grayscale and compared, no more warnings and error. Cheers and Thanks guys.

---

I am started to learn python and simplecv , using one of the example program in simple which is comparing two images, i am encountering this error. It first throws

> runtime warning: overflow encountered in int_scalars

```
map(lambda a,b: (a-b)**2,h1,h2))/len(h1))
```

Then throws the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\fs\python27files\imagecompare2.py", line 29, in <module>
    compare('belt.jpg','belt4.jpg')
  File "G:\fs\python27files\imagecompare2.py", line 20, in compare
    map(lambda a,b: (a-b)**2,h1,h2))/len(h1))
ValueError: math domain error
```

The code is

```
import math, operator
from SimpleCV import *

def compare(f1,f2):


        img = Image(f1)
        img1 = Image(f2)

        h1 = img.hueHistogram()
        h2 = img1.hueHistogram()
        #print h1
        #print h2
        print len(h1)
        print len(h2)
        f = map(lambda a,b: (a-b)**2,h1,h2)
        print f

        rms = math.sqrt(reduce(operator.add,
                            map(lambda a,b: (a-b)**2,h1,h2))/len(h1))
        #print rms


        #print h1.huePeaks()
        #print h2.huePeaks()


if __name__=='__main__':
   compare('belt.jpg','belt4.jpg')
```

as you can see i tried to print map alone in variable f, and encounters the same warning.

Finally i saw one related question here in SO which tells that setting up

dType(datatype) will remove the issue , but that is pertaining to numpy, I read

that simplecv is also incorporating numpy. any help regarding this?

> EDIT

i have pasted image showing the output of map function of resulting histograms, and i see one negative value in it.

[image]

the highlighted portion is showing the negative number. 
so how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing square root of negative number. You need to check your data and values in intermediate steps.

Minimal example:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
>>>
```

Comment: It can be fixed using [**`cmath.sqrt`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html#cmath.sqrt).

Comment: Actually, how can the sum of squares be negative?

Comment: @Peter Wood maybe because in some step `runtime warning: overflow encountered in int_scalars` occurs. SimpleCV bindings between C(++) and Python may return some negatives after positive number overflow. Unfortunately, we do not have Complete and Verifiable Example.

Answer (score 0):

Try load the pictures elsewhere. If this does not fail. Attempt testing them with standard simpleCV functions for image class [examples](http://tutorial.simplecv.org/en/latest/examples/shell.html) or [examples](http://tutorial.simplecv.org/en/latest/examples/basics.html). If this too works with your pictures the pictures are no the cause.

This exception means that there is an overflow in map(lambda a,b: (a-b)**2,h1,h2))/len(h1)). That can be you are nonnumbers. h1 or h2 are not linear sequences or of the same length. [map in python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) or [map in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function).

Check wether a-b can not be squared. For example list in list etc..

Comment: Try load the pictures elsewhere - if i am correct are you suggesting that should i try to open the picture with some other applications ? in that case well i am able to open both the pictures in all photo editors like gimp, photoshop , paint.net and ms paint as well.