# Python print key in all dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If I have a file that contains these dictionaries:

```
{
    "dict1" : {
        "data1" : "a",
        "data2" : "b",
        "data3" : "c",
        "data4" : "d",
        "data5" : "e"
    },
    "dict2" : {
        "data1" : "f",
        "data2" : "g",
        "data3" : "h",
        "data4" : "i",
        "data5" : "j"
    }
```

How would I go about accessing every dictionary key "data3". Such that the output would be:

```
c, h
```

Because there are multiple dictionaries inside the file I won't know the names. Is there anyway to iterate over them to pull out those keys?

Comment: Other than using `for`?

Comment: What names don't you know? The keys of the outer dict containing the inner dicts ("dict1" and "dict2" in your example)?

Comment: I'm loading this from a file which I have defined as self.players, I'm trying these methods but I'm not having much success. Is it an absolute must to create a name for the dictionaries like below? I.E. dct = .... and your_dict = ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> ', '.join(subdict['data3'] for subdict in maindict.values())
'c, h'
```

Explanation:

Your data is a dictionary `maindict`, where the keys are `'dict1'` and `'dict2'`.

```
>>> for key in maindict.keys():
...     print key
dict1
dict2
```

We're not interested in the keys, but want the values (which are actually two more dictionaries):

```
>>> for value in maindict.values():
...     print value
{"data1" : "a",
 "data2" : "b",
 "data3" : "c",
 "data4" : "d",
 "data5" : "e"}
{"data1" : "f",
 "data2" : "g",
 "data3" : "h",
 "data4" : "i",
 "data5" : "j"}
```

To get the value in the sub-dictionary corresponding to key `'data3'`:

```
>>> for subdict in maindict.values():
...     print subdict['data3']
c
h
```

You said you wanted a comma separated result. [**`str.join`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) allows you to join a sequence of strings using other characters as a separator:

```
>>> ', '.join(['William', 'Shatner', 'Speaks', 'Like', 'This'])
'William, Shatner, Speaks, Like, This'
```

The final piece of the puzzle is that we can generate sequences on the fly using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to create a generator:

```
>>> results = (subdict['data3'] for subdict in maindict.values())
>>> results
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x03115710>
```

You can pass a generator anywhere a sequence is expected:

```
>>> list(results)
['c', 'h']
```

So, we use a generator expression with `str.join`:

```
>>> ', '.join(subdict['data3'] for subdict in maindict.values())
'c, h'
```

Comment: This worked. But I'm not really sure how. Can you explain it to me? Edit: also Thank you!!!

Comment: Explanation added, sorry it's a bit long, and sorry the original answer was a bit short (c:

Comment: No! The explanation was perfect. I was able to follow it and I think I took away a better understanding of generator expressions and str.join. I plan to comment my code and provide a link to this answer for others to read.  Thanks again!!

Comment: is there a way to do this such that you do not have to hard-code `'data3'` and can expand it to iterate over all existing keys in the subdicts? I've been trying multiple different kinds of `for` loops but can't get it to work

Comment: @user5359531 I'm not sure I understand. You're probably best trying to formulate it as a new question with inputs, desired outputs, actual outputs and what you've tried. Then you'll have the whole of Stack Overflow working on your question instead of just little old me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dictionaries are only nested once like in your example, you can use a simple list comprehension, like this:

```
dct = [v["data3"] for v in oridict.values()]
```

This loops through your original dict (`oridict`), storing the values into `v`, which should be another dict, and then for every value `v` in the original dict, it gets the value of `"data3"`.

Comment: @MSeifert we don't need the keys of the outer dictionary, `oridict`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your dict like this (you forgot a closing `}`):

```
dct = {
    "dict1" : {
        "data1" : "a",
        "data2" : "b",
        "data3" : "c",
        "data4" : "d",
        "data5" : "e"
    },
    "dict2" : {
        "data1" : "f",
        "data2" : "g",
        "data3" : "h",
        "data4" : "i",
        "data5" : "j"}
    }
```

Just use a generator expression:

```
>>> i_key = 'data3' # inner key
>>> for value in (dct[o_key][i_key] for o_key in dct if i_key in dct[o_key]):
...     print(value)
h
c
```

This will only print the `data3` value if it exists in the nested dictionary otherwise it is simply skipped.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, "dict1" and "dict2" are unknown names, and of unknown quantity, but each of them have a "data3" that you would like to get the value of? (by the way, "data3" is the key, c and h are the values).

To do this, lets assume the whole thing has been read in and is stored in, say, `all_data`.   If you don't know how to do this, I suggest looking at the `json` module, as this is basically in json format.

```
for k,v in all_data.items():
    # v will now hold the sub-dictionary, so we can just grab "data3":
    print v.get('data3',"")  # I used the .get() method incase "data3" doesn't exist
```

Comment: did you mean `v.get("data3")`?

Comment: oops, yes.  Fixed.

Comment: Why not `all_data.items()`? `iteritems` only works for 2.x, whereas `items` works for 2 and 3.

Comment: Fair point -- I only really use 2.x, which is why I'm used to iteritems().  Edited to improve.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this code:

```
TargetKey= 'data3'
output = map(lambda D:S[D].get(TargetKey, ''), S )
', '.join(output) # or simply loop throw output
```

Comment: This code is very unpythonic, it breaks pep8 in like 5 places, and uses [map](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10973817/1357527) instead of a list comprehension