# Can't delete not last single object

Tags: python, list

My code should recieve a list of numbers and then output on the screen the only numbers which repeat more then once. I don't know why but it don't work with the numbers in the middle of list. My code:

```
a = [int(i) for i in (input().split())]
a.sort()
for number in a:
    if a.count(number)==1:
        a.remove(number)
    else:
        a.remove(a.count(number)-a.count(number)+number)
for number in a:
    print(number, end=' ')
```

I tried changing if on while on 4th string, but then the last number is left in the list.
It should work like:

> Sample Input 1: 4 8 0 3 4 2 0 3 Sample Output 1: 0 3 4
>
> Sample Input 2: 10 Sample Output 2:
>
> Sample Input 3: 1 1 2 2 3 3 Sample Output 3: 1 2 3
>
> Sample Input 4: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 Sample Output 4: 1 2

Comment: `a.count(number)-a.count(number)+number` = `number`, right? You should use `collections.Counter` for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this problem using `set` instead:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
print(" ".join(map(str, set(i for i in a if a.count(i) > 1))))
```

---

**Explanation:**

Firstly, it looks like you should read up on the [`map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function) function. Instead of `a = [int(i) for i in (input().split())]`, you can just use `list(map(int, input().split()))`, which is much more Pythonic.

Secondly, the important part of the second line is `set(i for i in a if a.count(i) > 1)`, which just creates a new list containing only the duplicates from `a` (i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 2, 3]` becomes `[2, 3, 2, 3]` and then applies `set` to it, which converts `[2, 3, 2, 3]` into `{2, 3}` (which is a `set` object).

In case you're wondering what `map(str, ...)` is for, it's so that you can print each of the elements inside your new `set` (e.g. `{2, 3}`).

Comment: I am learnin python on a course and haven't known that yet. But it look pretty fine and easy. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @AntonL. I've added an explanation to help you understand everything that's going on :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in lib [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count list items and filter it by a required condition.

```
import collections

ints = map(int, input().split())
count = collections.Counter(ints)
print filter(lambda x: count[x] > 1, count)
```