# Python append value to a list returned from a function via for loop

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, append

I have a function:

```
def function(x,y):
    do something
    print a,b
    return a,b
```

Now I use a for loop like:

```
for i in range(10,100,10):
    function(i,30)
```

which prints the values `a,b` for the given input values via the for loop. 
It also returns `a,b` if I say for example `function(10,30)` like:

```
Out[50]: (0.25725063633960099, 0.0039189363571677958)
```

**I would like to append the values of `a,b` obtained for my different input parameters `(x,y)` via the for loop to two empty lists.**

I tried

```
for i in range(10,100,10):
    list_a,list_b = function(i,30)
```

but `list_a` and `list_b` are still empty.

**EDIT:**

**I have also tried:**

```
list_a = []
list_b = []
for i in range(10,100,10):
    list_a.append(function(i,30)[0])
    list_b.append(function(i,30)[1])
```

But `list_a` and `list_b` are empty!

**What I don't understand is that**, when I call

`function(10,30)[0]`

for instance, **it outputs a value! But why am I not able to append it to a list?**

***Here is the entire function as asked by a few.***

```
def function(N,bins):
    sample = np.log10(m200_1[n200_1>N]) # can be any 1D array
    mean,scatter = stats.norm.fit(sample) #Gives the paramters of the fit to the histogram
    err_std = scatter/np.sqrt(len(sample))

    if N<30:
        x_fit = np.linspace(sample.min(),sample.max(),100)
        pdf_fitted = stats.norm.pdf(x_fit,loc=mean,scale=scatter) #Gives the PDF, given the parameters from norm.fit
        print "scatter for N>%s is %s" %(N,scatter)
        print "error on scatter for N>%s is %s" %(N,err_std)
        print "mean for N>%s is %s" %(N,mean)  

    else:
        x_fit = np.linspace(sample.min(),sample.max(),100)
        pdf_fitted = stats.norm.pdf(x_fit,loc=mean,scale=scatter) #Gives the PDF, given the parameters from norm.fit
        print "scatter for N>%s is %s" %(N,scatter) 
        print "error on scatter for N>%s is %s" %(N,err_std)
        print "mean for N>%s is %s" %(N,mean)

    return scatter,err_std
```

Comment: You are setting the lists on each iteration to the return values of the function. I believe you are trying to `.append(val)`.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Please post entire code, every answer below will and does work. The only other explanation would be an error elsewhere.

Comment: Yes @TheLazyScripter. I think the issue must lie within the function, but it seems very strange if all these answers result in empty lists. Even if the function returned `None` or an empty string, these will still be appended to the lists.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter: please have a look at the entire function. It returns the two values as a tuple, i.e. `(0.16552264676265405, 0.011976798379824433)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Please have a look at the entire function.

Comment: The function lacks correct indentation

Comment: @Chris_Rands: realy!! That was just a typo.. apart from that what do you find?

Answer (score 5):

you can use list comprehension first, get list_a, list_b via zip.

```
def function(x,y):
    return x,y

result = [function(i,30) for i in range(10,100,10)]
list_a, list_b = zip(*result)
```

Comment: `list_a` and `list_b` are still empty!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
# Define a simple test function
def function_test(x,y): 
    return x,y

# Initialize two empty lists
list_a = []
list_b = []
# Loop over a range
for i in range(10,100,10):
        a = function_test(i,30) # The output of the function is a tuple, which we put in "a"
        # Append the output of the function to the lists
        # We access each element of the output tuple "a" via indices
        list_a.append(a[0])
        list_b.append(a[1])
# Print the final lists      
print(list_a)
print(list_b)
```

Comment: Can you please add some explenation to your answer? Only showing code can be confusing for some people.

Comment: Thanks @AndréKool , I added some comments to the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that:

```
list_a = []
list_b = []

for i in range(10,100,10):
    a, b = function(i,30)
    list_a.append(a)
    list_b.append(b)
```

Answer (score -2):

you may need to try map() function, which is more friendly~~

[Understanding the map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function)

which should be the same as in python 3: 
def map(func, iterable):
    for i in iterable:
        yield func(i)

under python 2 map will return the full list