# Giving name to element in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to give names to call and concatenate the process data later.

```
from glob import glob
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np

emot= glob('path/emotion_***.nii')

em_1 = nib.load(emot[0]).get_data()
em_2 = nib.load(emot[1]).get_data()

em_1 = np.reshape(em_1[:,36], (90,104))
em_2 = np.reshape(em_2[:,36], (90,104))

data_emot = np.concatenate([em_1,em_2])
```

How could I do it the faster way with more than 100 elements in the glob list?

Additional info, the `nib.load()` and `.get_data()` are the **nibabel** process. Thus, if they load together with **numpy reshape**, str is called, rather the loaded process.

Comment: use a dictionary or a list, you don't *need* a name for each. `em_1` or `em[1]` does it make any difference?

Comment: how to? that is a list already.

Comment: `em = [np.reshape(nib.load(x.get_data()[:,36], (90,104)) for x in emot]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply using a [*for-loop*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

```
from glob import glob
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np

emot = glob('path/emotion_***.nii')
to_concat = []

for el_i in emot:
    em_i = np.reshape(nib.load(el_i).get_data()[:,36], (90,104))
    to_concat.append(em_i)
```

So that you can *concatenate the process data later*.

```
data_emot = np.concatenate(to_concat)
```

#### To go further

Note that the *for-loop* above can be rewritten more compactly. As follows

```
to_concat = [np.reshape(nib.load(el_i).get_data()[:,36], (90,104))\
             for el_i in emot]
```

Or using the python-native [`map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function) function

```
to_concat = map(lambda el_i:np.reshape(nib.load(el_i).get_data()[:,36], (90,104)),\
                emot)
```

Comment: @Nufa. Also, if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: FYI my comment does exactly the same but is written in a more compact, pythonic way using list comprehension.

Comment: @Julien. The OP does not seem to be at this level. Also, your code has a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: The OP should strive to be at this level ;), just copied and pasted OP's post, which had the syntax error already ;)

Comment: @Julien. I know what you did. Actually I first did just like you :) But you are right. I am going to add this to my answer.

Comment: actually this one does not work, because when it is trying to '.get_data()', the python gives and error that saying this is a string, 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_data''.

Comment: @Nufa. It works now. Check it. This `AttributeError` what due to the fact that the enclosing parenthesis of the function `nib.load()` was not placed correctly.

Comment: yup, it works now. Thank you. I've upped the answer. both.