# How to map values of different data types in a single line of code from a single line of input in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose the input is: string integer integer.
Now i need to map only the 2nd and 3rd input to integer.

```
name, d, j = input().split()
d = int(d)
j = int(j)
```

Is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You could also do this:

```
name, d, j = input().split()
d,j = map(int,[d,j])
```

But I don't really see the benefit. There's nothing wrong with what you already have. Remember, fewer lines of code is not a goal unto itself.

Comment: `Remember, fewer lines of code is not a goal unto itself.`, +1 for that.

Comment: I suppose I should qualify that with "Unless you're doing a code golf challenge." Since Python is a fairly popular code golf language.

Comment: @mypetlion what's the difference between using ( ) vs [ ] for 2nd map parameter? I used both and both worked. eg: map(int, (x,y)) worked same as map(int, [x,y])

Comment: @rohegde7 Nothing, really. Personal preference. I'll typically default to `[]` for throwaway iterables like that, but use `()` if you like. For trivial situations like this, it's pretty rare that it will make a difference. By "rare" I mean that I can't think of any such situations off the top of my head.

Comment: @rohegde7, the `2nd map parameter` is an iterable. So it can be a list or a tuple or any other iterable. [Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10973804/7832176)

Answer (score 1):

```
name, d, j = [int(b) if i >=1 else b for i,b in enumerate(input().split())]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the purely academic challenge of squeezing it into one line, you could use the singleton list/iterator trick:

```
name, d, j = next((x, *map(int, y)) for x, *y in ['john 3 4'.split()])
```

But pls never do this in production code ;)