# Converting Python Dictionary to List [complex]

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am very new to python and this forum :)
I have been struggling with dictionary and can really use some help.

For my question, the Input is:

```
frontier = [
              { 'state': (2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1), 'path': [ 'PULL' ] },
              { 'state': (2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 1), 'path': [ 'SWAP','PULL' ] },
              { 'state': (2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 3), 'path': [ 'SWAP' ] },
              { 'state': (2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1), 'path': [ 'PUSH', 'PUSH' ] },

            ]
```

We are told that the assigned value of each action:

- PUSH: 5
- PULL: 6
- SWAP: 8
- FLIP: 2

  eg. if [ push, swap] = 5+8

For this question, every state has an assigned value (heuristic) that I have calculated.

However, calculating the value of actions has me stumped. I have tried coding by splitting the item['path'] but the list it creates cannot be used. *I have no idea how to approach this.*

I want to make a list for the action. For the above question, it will look:

```
[6, 14, 8, 10]
```

Can someone please tell me how it can be achieve with explanation and code for the given example?

Comment: So basically the sum?

Comment: The sum of the actions for any given state. 
The main problem I have is how to convert it to list and assign it value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  What you posted is not a problem specification.  As given, you're simply asking us to write your code for you -- and without a proper description.

Comment: I apologise. My code was actually useless so I thought it was better to leave it out. The reason why I gave a description of it ( I have tried coding by splitting the item['path'] but the list it creates cannot be used.)
I will keep it in mind next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
frontier = [{ 'state': (2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1), 'path': [ 'PULL' ] },
            { 'state': (2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 1), 'path': [ 'SWAP','PULL' ] },
            { 'state': (2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 3), 'path': [ 'SWAP' ] },
            { 'state': (2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1), 'path': [ 'PUSH', 'PUSH' ] }]

d = {'PUSH': 5, 'PULL': 6, 'SWAP': 8, 'FLIP': 2}

res = [sum(map(d.get, item['path'])) for item in frontier]

print(res)

[6, 14, 8, 10]
```

**Explanation**

- Create a dictionary mapping actions to values.
- Use `sum` with `map` to lazily calculate the the sum of all actions in a dictionary.
- Use a list comprehension to loop through each dictionary in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you elaborate a bit on what 'map' does?

Comment: Sure, `map` applies a function to *each value* in an iterable, and returns an iterable. The function in this case is `d.get`, i.e. get a value from the dictionary given key. The iterable is the items in `item[path]`. You find more about `map` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = []
for item in frontier:
    item_path_value = 0
    for action in item['path']:
        item_path_value += action.value
    result.append(item_path_value)
```

where `action.value` should return the value for that specific action

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
frontier = [
              { 'state': (2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1), 'path': [ 'PULL' ] },
              { 'state': (2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 1), 'path': [ 'SWAP','PULL' ] },
              { 'state': (2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 3), 'path': [ 'SWAP' ] },
              { 'state': (2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1), 'path': [ 'PUSH', 'PUSH' ] },

            ]

d = dict(PUSH=5, PULL=6, SWAP=8, FLIP=2)

out = [sum(d.get(i,0) for i in x['path']) for x in frontier]
print(out)
```

Returns:

```
[6, 14, 8, 10]
```

The `.get(key, default)` function is your friend here. It will fetch a value from a dictionary given a key and if not found returns the default value. We sum this for all items in the dictionary value `path`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the total sum for each path, create a dictionary storing the values for each action:

```
frontier = [{'path': ['PULL'], 'state': (2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1)}, {'path': ['SWAP', 'PULL'], 'state': (2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 1)}, {'path': ['SWAP'], 'state': (2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 3)}, {'path': ['PUSH', 'PUSH'], 'state': (2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1)}]
actions = {'PUSH': 5, 'PULL': 6, 'SWAP': 8, 'FLIP': 2}
final_dict = [{**b, **{'path':sum(actions.get(i) for i in b['path'])}} for b in frontier]
```

Output:

```
[{'state': (2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1), 'path': 6}, {'state': (2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 1), 'path': 14}, {'state': (2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 3), 'path': 8}, {'state': (2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1), 'path': 10}]
```

For the condensed result:

```
print([i['path'] for i in final_dict])
```

Output:

```
[6, 14, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this approach:

```
frontier = [
              { 'state': (2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1), 'path': [ 'PULL' ] },
              { 'state': (2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 1), 'path': [ 'SWAP','PULL' ] },
              { 'state': (2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 3), 'path': [ 'SWAP' ] },
              { 'state': (2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1), 'path': [ 'PUSH', 'PUSH' ] },

            ]

data = {'PUSH': 5, 'PULL': 6, 'SWAP': 8, 'FLIP': 2}


for j,i in enumerate(frontier):
    actions=[]
    for k in i['path']:
        actions.append(data[k])

    frontier[j]['path']=sum(actions)

print(frontier)
```

output:

```
[{'state': (2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 1), 'path': 6}, {'state': (2, 4, 5, 0, 3, 1), 'path': 14}, {'state': (2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 3), 'path': 8}, {'state': (2, 0, 5, 4, 3, 1), 'path': 10}]
```