# having a list in python,using lambda and map/filter to generate new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

i have a list:

```
seq = ['soup','dog','salad','cat','great']
```

As per the definition of filter, below code fetches the correct result:

```
list(filter(lambda w: w[0]=='s',seq))

['soup','salad']
```

i.e returning the list containing only words starting with `'s'`

but if i am using map function, it is returning the list as true/false:

```
list(map(lambda w: w[0]=='s',seq))`

[True, False, True, False, False]
```

please explain the map function w.r.t. to the above example

Answer (score 2):

`map` applies a function to a sequence and returns a generator.

Example:

```
k = list(map(int,["1","2","3"]))
```

`int()` is a function `string->int` hence `k` becomes:

```
k ==  [1,2,3] # (a list of ints)
```

Your lambda is a fuction `string->bool` that takes a `string` and evaluates the first char to be `'s'` or not:

```
lambda w: w[0]=='s'
```

As a function of `string->bool`, your result is a `list` of `bool`s when using `list(map(lambda w: w[0]=='s', seq))` to apply your lambda to your sequence.

---

Btw. you could also have done it as list comprehension:

```
s_seq = [x for x in seq if x[0]=='s'] # which is closer to what filter does...
```

This might shed more light on `map()`: [Understanding the map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function)

Comment: Great answer. Something I didn't know but is very much worth noting. Thanks.