# Transform the elements of list from [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']] to ['a b', 'c d']

Tags: python, list

due to some problems with lemmatization I had to import one list in the form of:

```
list_a = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]
```

Now I want to count the frequency of each elements, but the list is unhashable in this form. Therefore I want to convert it into:

```
list_b = ['a b', 'c d', 'a b']]
```

I know that this is a very self-made problem and probably a dirty workaround, but in the imported form of list_b the lemmatization only lemmatized single-elements of the list and did not touch any composed elements.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: If you use tuples instead of lists, then it should be hashable without the need to significantly change the structure of the data.

Comment: `list_b = [' '.join(l) for l in list_a]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with string concatenation:

```
list_a = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]

list_b = [x + ' ' + y for x, y in list_a]
```

You can also use `str.join` (useful if there are more than two elements in the sublists):

```
list_b = [' '.join(a) for a in list_a]
```

Output:

```
['a b', 'c d', 'a b']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use map function:

```py
list_a = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b']]

list_b = list(map(' '.join, a))
# ['a b', 'c d', 'a b']
```

[Understanding the map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function)