# Iterations and lambda functions

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply a lambda function to several columns but I am not sure how to loop through the columns. Basically I have Column1 - Column50 and I want the exact same thing to happen on each but can't figure out how to iterate through them where x.column is below. Is there a way to do this?

```
for column in df:
   df[column] = df.apply(lambda x: x.datacolumn * x.datacolumn2 if x.column >= x.datacolumn3, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you are trying to accomplish here?  From your code, it looks like you want to do something like "set the value of `df[column]` to `df["datacolumn"] * df["datacolumn2"]` if `df[column] >= df["datacolumn3"]` for all `column`s in `df`.  Am I interpreting your intention correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like `map()`? `map()` applies a function to every item in a list (or other iterable) and returns a list containing the results.

Here's [an eloquent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427528/11639533) of how it works (way better than what I could write).

At a certain point, however, declaring a normal function and/or using a for loop might be easier.

Comment: Disclaimer: This isn't pandas-specific. I'm not very experienced in the panda realm, and thus it's entirely possible that this won't work for pandas data structures.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you are missing the `else` branch (what to do when the `if` condition is `False`?), and for accessing Panda's `Series` (the input for the lambda function) elements, you could use indexes.

For example, setting to `0`, if the condition does not stand:

```
for column in df:
    df[column] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0] * x[1] if x[0] >= x[2] else 0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest to extract each column as a list, perform the operation, then write the result back into the dataframe.

```
for column in df:
   temp = [x for x in df.loc[:, column]]      #pull a list out using loc
   if temp[0] > temp[2]:
       temp[0] = temp[0] * temp[1]
   df.loc[:, column] = temp                   #overwrite original df column
```

The above leaves data unchanged if condition is not met.