# How to change value ID to model attribute in Queryset

Tags: django, python-3.x

Django QuerySets return the PK of the associated objects but I need the attribute name. For example `Sitting.objects.filter(complete=True).values('user')` would return a QuerySet like: `<QuerySet[{'user':2}, {'user':3}]>`. How do I easily convert the `2` to `user.get_full_name()` or such?

To give an idea of what I was trying:

```
tests_taken = Sitting.objects.filter(complete=True).values('user')
for test in tests_taken:
   try:
      tests_taken[test]['user'] = Employee.objects.get(pk=test['user'])
   except TypeError:
      pass
print(tests_taken)
```

It just seems really inefficient and I am not really sure what to do from here.

This:

```
qs = Sitting.objects.filter(complete=True).values('user')
tests_taken = [{'user': Employee.objects.filter(pk=user).get_full_name()} for user in qs]
print(tests_taken)
```

Gives this error:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'

**Models**:

```
class Sitting(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        verbose_name=_("User"),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Employee(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def get_full_name(self):
        # returns self.first_name + self.last_name
```

**My goal**:

`{'user':2}` should be converted to `{'user':'John Doe'}`

Comment: Please show the models that you are referencing, I'm not sure what `.get_full_name()` is.  It looks like this would be trivial to implement via a subquery.

Comment: `Sitting` is the model being referenced with the attribute `user`. `Employee` is the my `AbstractBaseUser` model so I would like to call `get_full_name()`, which is a built-in Django method for retrieving the users full name, and then switch the Id in the dictionary to the Employee's full name. Then I am going to pass this data to a JS chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the optimized version of your code:

```
qs = Sitting.objects.filter(complete=True).values('user_id')
employees = Employee.objects.filter(id__in=qs)
```

### Edit:

you don't really need that `map` statement, and It would be most efficient to call `get_full_name` as you iterate over your queryset. 
For example:

```
qs = Sitting.objects.filter(complete=True).values('user_id')
employees = Employee.objects.filter(id__in=qs)

for employee in employees:
    print(employee.get_full_name())
```

Or in a template:

```
{% for employee in employees %}
    <h1> {{ employee.get_full_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

### Edit 2:

I'm confused about why you want to convert your queryset into a list of objects, but alas, Here you go:

```
employees = [
    {'user':user.get_full_name()} 
    for user in Employee.objects.filter(id__in=qs)
]
```

I'm going to assume you don't actually want your data to look like:

```
[{'user':'john doe'}, {'user':'jane doe'}]
```

Here is what I think you want:

```
employees = Employee.objects.filter(id__in=qs)

[{'id':user.id, 'full_name':user.full_name} for user in employees]
```

Or as a list of tuples:

```
[(user.id, user.full_name) for user in employees]
```

Comment: Updated it to include models

Comment: @DavidAlford What happens when you run my query?  It looks like it should be working.

Comment: Yes, it does - thank you. Would you mind explaining it a little bit? I don't know `map()` and `lambda` very well but will look into them. If you give give context that may help though.

Comment: @DavidAlford I added an update.  I'm not really sure why I used `map` ;P

Comment: @DavidAlford If you still want to learn what map does, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function) gives a few good explanations.

Comment: This switches the user id to the user name which is fine. But I am wondering how to switch it *inside the dictionary*. I probably should have stated that before I accepted the answer since I already know how to do a lookup with the PK.

Comment: Basically, it takes a callable (function, lambda, etc), and applies that callable to every item in a list.

Comment: @DavidAlford what do you mean?

Comment: See: `My goal:` above.

Comment: My whole goal is to convert the QS to the proper format then convert to an array to pass to a Javascript HighChart for displaying the data.

Comment: This has probably been my worst-phrased question yet and I apologize for that XD. I am not trying to get a list of objects, just converting the PK to the string format of the username for display. But I need it in a list of lists which I was going to handle after the dictionary looked correct :P

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use methods in values but instead, you can do like this,

```
queryset = Sitting.objects.filter(complete=True)
tests_taken = [{'full_name':user.get_full_name()} for user in queryset]
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to try to use your method though I may have not given enough information at the start which resulted in shooting myself in the foot.

Comment: Please change your qs = Sitting.objects.filter(complete=True).values('user')
to qs = Sitting.objects.filter(complete=True)