# Cannot understand these errors and outputs in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, compiler-errors

```py
print("Enter number of test cases and length of each string")
t,s=map(input,range(2))
print(t,s)
```

It prompts as Enter number of test cases and length of each string
03
13. Why is there 0 and 1 before 3's?

The below line shows ouput

```py
t,s=map(lambda x :input ,range(2))
 OUTPUT-<built-in function input> <built-in function input>
WHY IS THAT?
```

Whereas this line :

```py
t,s=map(int(input()),range(2))
OUTPUT: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\gridchallenge.py", line 2, in <module>
    t,s=map(int(input()),range(2))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

WHY IS IT NOT CALLABLE?

t,s=map(input(),range(2))

THE ABOVE LINE HOWEVER CAUSES THIS ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\gridchallenge.py", line 2, in <module>
    t,s=map(input(),range(2))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

WHY IN THE FIRST CASE NO ERROR AND IN LAST ONE THERE IS.
python
t,s=map(lambda x: int(input()),range(2))


ALSO THIS ONE WORKS JUST FINE.
WHY USING LAMBDA MAKES IT WORK FINE BUT WITHOUT LAMBDA AS IN THE 3rd ONE IT THROWS ERROR.
```

Comment: `t,s=map(input, ['']*2)`?

Comment: For your first snippet, I think that when `map` calls `input()` is also passes the parameter of the items coming from `range(2)` which is `0` and then `1`. It seems that `input()` just prints its parameter. The last snippet results in the error because, as I have mentioned, `map` calls its first parameter.

Comment: In the middle snippet, when `map` calls the `lambda`, it returns the built-in `input` without calling it. Did you mean: `t,s=map(lambda _ :input() ,range(2))`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function)

Comment: And, please stop SHOUTING.

Comment: Thanx for the help .

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Enter number of test cases and length of each string")
t,s=map(input,range(2))
print(t,s)
```

You can understand this by breaking it down into pieces.

[`range(2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) returns a sequence of two numbers, starting from `0`. So the first number in the sequence will be `0` and the second will be `1`.

[`map(f, sequence)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) will call function `f` once for each item in `sequence`, and collect the results into a new sequence. Since we have `map(input, range(2))` it will call the function `input` twice, once with `0` as input and once with `1` as input, i.e. `input(0)` then `input(1)`.

Each time [`input(prompt)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) is called, it displays the prompt and waits you to type an input string. So the first time the prompt is `0` and the second time the prompt is `1`.

---

```
t,s=map(lambda x :input ,range(2))
 OUTPUT-<built-in function input> <built-in function input>
```

> WHY IS THAT?

`lambda x: input` defines a lambda-function that takes one argument (`x`) and returns the function `input` as a value. Functions can be passed around as values, indeed we want to give `map` a function as its first argument. But in this case we probably don't want to return the function `input` as a value when our lambda-function is called. Instead we want to *call* it. To call a function with no arguments, you write a pair of parentheses with nothing between them. E.g. `input()`. So here's what you could write instead:

```
t,s=map(lambda x :input() ,range(2))
```

---

```
t,s=map(int(input()),range(2))
OUTPUT: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\gridchallenge.py", line 2, in <module>
    t,s=map(int(input()),range(2))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.
```

The first argument to `map` should be a function, because `map` itself will call it (repeatedly). But in this case, rather than passing it a function we are passing it a number. You can try instead:

```
t,s=map(lambda x :int(input()) ,range(2))
```

In this case the lambda function tells Python that we don't want to evaluate `int(input())` *immediately*, but instead to create a function that will do that when it is called.

---

```
t,s=map(input(),range(2))
```

> THE ABOVE LINE HOWEVER CAUSES THIS ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\gridchallenge.py", line 2, in <module>
    t,s=map(input(),range(2))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.
```

> WHY IN THE FIRST CASE NO ERROR AND IN LAST ONE THERE IS.

This is again the same issue. `map(input(), range(2))` will call the input function straight away and pass its return value (a string) to `map` as an argument, whereas `map(input, range(2))` passes the function `input` *itself* as an argument.