# python args operator and map function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

1. How does `args` work? I know it is used when you don't know how many arguments you may pass to a function, but I need deeper explanation. Do they run function for each argument passed?

```py
    def buy_sell_hold(*args):
        cols = [c for c in args]
        requirement = 0.02
        for col in cols:
            if col > requirement:
                return 1
            if col < -requirement:
                return -1
        return 0
    def extract_featuresets(ticker):
        tickers, df = process_data_for_labels(ticker)

        df['{}_target'.format(ticker)] = list(map( buy_sell_hold,
                                               df['{}_1d'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_2d'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_3d'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_4d'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_5d'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_6d'.format(ticker)],
                                               df['{}_7d'.format(ticker)] ))
    vals = df['{}_target'.format(ticker)].values.tolist()
    return vals
```

2. Vals are single list how so, I'm lost.

Comment: These questions have been asked multiple times, it is advisable to search the already available knowledge base of SO, or Google for that matter, before asking a question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5431791) e.g.  answer on [`map`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10973766/5431791)

Answer (score 0):

python has two types of variable length arguments:

- `*args` (Non Keyword Arguments)
- `**kwargs` (Keyword Arguments)

When you define a function with `*args`, you effectively take arguments and collect them into a list. So;

```py
def foo(*a):
    # a here is a tuple: (2,3,4,5)
    print(a)

foo(2,3,4,5)
>>>
(2,3,4,5)
```

When you define a function with `**kwargs`, you effectively take named arguments and collect them into a dict. So;

```py
def zoo(**b):
    # b here is a dict: {'test': 2, 'abc': 'def'}
    print(b)
zoo(test=2, abc='def')
>>>
{'test': 2, 'abc': 'def'}
```

When you want to pass variable arguments from a list or a dict, you can use similarly:

```py
def xxx(a=2, b=4):
    print(a+b)
kw = {'a': 5, 'b': 7}
xxx(**kw)
>>>
12
```

see: [https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs#:~:text=Python%20has%20*args%20which%20allow,to%20pass%20variable%20length%20arguments](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs#:%7E:text=Python%20has%20*args%20which%20allow,to%20pass%20variable%20length%20arguments).