# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'Value'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

No matter what I do I cannot execute draw_plot(d) due to this float error.

"The issue is that n.data is a Value object, not a float. To fix this, you need to extract the data from the Value object using the data attribute:"

ive tried float(n.data.n.data) etc.....nothing works ....not sure what to do................................is Andrej Karpathy around?

````
    class Value:
      def __init__(self, data,_children=(),_op='',label=''):
      self.data = data
      self._prev=set(_children)
      self._op=_op
      self.label=label
    # REPR allows for nicer looking expression in python
      def __repr__(self):
        return f"Value(data={self.data})"
      def __add__(self, other):
        out = Value(self.data + other.data,(self,other), '+')
        return out
      def __mul__(self, other):
        out = Value(self.data * other.data,'*')
        return out
    a = Value(2.0, label='a')
    b = Value(-3.0,label='b')
    c = Value(10.0,label='c')
    e=a*b;e.label='e'
    # a * b + c
    d=e + c; d.label='d'
    f=Value(-2.0, label='f')
    L=d*f
    d._prev
    d._op

    !pip install graphviz
    import graphviz
    from graphviz import Digraph
    def trace(root):
      #builds a set of all nodes and edges in a graph
      nodes,edges=set(),set()
      def build(v):
        if v not in nodes:
          nodes.add(v)
        for  child in map(Value, v._prev):
          edges.add((child,v))
          build(child)
      build(root)
      return nodes,edges
    def draw_dot(root):
        dot = Digraph(format='svg', graph_attr={'rankdir': 'LR'})
        nodes,edges=trace(root)
        for n in nodes:
          uid=str(id(n))
        # for any value in the graph create a record (rectanglualr node for it)
          dot.node(name=uid,label="{data %.4f}" % float(n.data,), shape='record')
          if n._op:
        #If this value is a result of some operation, create a node for it
            dot.node(name=uid+n._op,label=n._op)
        # and connect this node to it
            dot.edge(uid+n._op,uid)

        for n1,n2 in edges:
        #connect n1 to the op node of n2
          dot.edge(str(id(n1)),str(id(n2))+n2._op)

          return dot


    draw_dot(d)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973766/understanding-the-map-function) Tl;dr when you say `for child in map(Value, v._prev)` you're writing something like `for child in [Value(i) for i in v._prev]`

Comment: I still dont understand ...

Comment: You're creating new `Value` objects and passing existing objects as the `data` argument...