# How do I compare 2D lists for equality in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

Given two lists:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

How would I write `compare` such that:

```
compare(a,b) => true
```

Comment: .. won't `a == b` serve your purpose?

Comment: Not necessarily.  For example, if the elements of the list were strings (and you wanted case insensitivity), or floats and you wanted a tolerance for numerical error, then `==` wouldn't work.  Depends on your expected types.

Comment: @sdasdadas Try out a few things before asking questions :) The lists are Python objects; `==` tests equality for Python objects. It's the same if testing the equality of two normal lists.

Comment: ... Maybe I'm the minority but I'm glad that there's always an exact dumb question on SO when I encounter a dumb question myself.

Comment: @yzn-pku That's good because I've been generating them for years now.

Comment: Related [`numpy`]: [Comparing two numpy arrays for equality, element-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you want this:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> b = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> a == b
True
```

Note: `==` not useful when List are unordered e.g (*notice order in `a`, and in `b`*)

```
>>> a = [[3,4],[1,2]]
>>> b = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> a == b
False
```

See this question for further reference: [How to compare a list of lists/sets in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105777/how-to-compare-a-list-of-lists-sets-in-python)

**Edit**: Thanks to @dr jimbob

If you want to compare after sorting you can use `sorted(a)==sorted(b)`.
But again a point, if `c = [[4,3], [2,1]]` then `sorted(c) == sorted(a) == False` because, `sorted(c)` being different `[[2,1],[4,3]]` (*not in-depth sort*)

<sub>for this you have to use techniques from linked answer. Since I am learning Python too :)</sub>

Comment: The last part isn't right.  `a.sort()` sorts `a` in place and then returns `None`.  So `a.sort() == None` will be `True`, and your `a.sort()==b.sort()` evaluates to `None == None`.  Try getting a `False`; e.g., let `b=[]`. (Note its better style to use `is` comparison when checking for None). Now, `sorted(a) == sorted(b)` will work.  Granted note if you have `a = [[1,2],[3,4]]`, `b = [[3,4],[1,2]]` and `c = [[4,3], [2,1]]`, then only `sorted(a)` and `sorted(b)` will be equal (both being `[[1,2],[3,4]]`), with `sorted(c)` being different (`[[2,1],[4,3]]`).

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
def compare(a, b): return a == b
```

Another way is using `lambda` to create an anonymous function:

```
compare = lambda a, b: a == b
```