# Fastest method for comparing ranges of multidimensional lists

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, search, optimization

**Context:** I am trying to write an A* search in an unknown environment. To do this, I am maintaining a representation of the environment in a 2-D or 3-D list (depending on the environment), and another n-D list that represents the agent's knowledge of the environment.

When the agent moves, I check the area around them with the actual environment. If there is a discrepancy, their map gets updated, and I run A* again.

**Problem:** What is the fastest method to check if there is a difference between the ranges of these two lists?

**Naive Solution:**

```
from itertools import product
from random import randint

width, height = 10, 10
known_environment = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
actual_environment = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

# Populate with obstacles
for i in xrange(10):
    x = randint(0, len(actual_environment) - 1)
    y = randint(0, len(actual_environment[x]) - 1)
    actual_environment[x][y] += 1

# Run A* and get a path
path = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4),
        (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]  # dummy path

# Traverse path, checking for "new" obstacles
for step in path:
    x, y = step[0], step[1]

    # check area around agent
    for (i, j) in product([-1, 0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]):
        # don't bother checking out-of-bounds
        if not 0 <= x + i < width:
            continue
        if not 0 <= y + j < height:
            continue
        # internal map doesn't match real world, update
        if not known_environment[x + i][ y + j] == actual_environment[x + i][ y + j]:
            known_environment[x + i][ y + j] = actual_environment[x + i][ y + j]
            # Re-run A*
```

This works, but it feels inefficient. I'm thinking I could replace the loop with something like `set(known_environment).intersection(actual_environment)` to check if there is a discrepancy, and *then* update if needed; but this can probably be improved upon as well.

Thoughts?

**Edit:** I've switched over to numpy slicing, and use array_equal instead of sets.

```
# check area around agent
left = x - sight if x - sight >= 0 else 0
right = x + sight if x + sight < width else width - 1
top = y - sight if y - sight >= 0 else 0
bottom = y + sight if y + sight < height else height - 1

known_section = known_environment[left:right + 1, top:bottom + 1]
actual_section = actual_environment[left:right + 1, top:bottom + 1]
if not np.array_equal(known_section, actual_section):
    known_environment[left:right + 1, top:bottom + 1] = actual_section
```

Comment: Did you already have the time to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105777/how-to-compare-a-list-of-lists-sets-in-python ? ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant, thanks, but I also need the *positions* in the matrix of the different elements so that I could update the "map".

Comment: Why are you using two environments? Just use and modify the global environment in your A* search.

Comment: And I'd also suggest using `[[0] * width] * height` instead of that long environment initialization statement.

Comment: @EvilTak, I've switched over to numpy, which allows for the nicer: known_environment = np.zeros(shape=(width, height), dtype=int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should already be a tad faster, when you employ the solution concept from the link given in my comment to the question.

I modified / hacked up a bit the given code and tried:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import product
from random import randint

width, height = 10, 10
known_env = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
actual_env = [[0 for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

# Populate with obstacles
for i in xrange(10):
    x = randint(0, len(actual_env) - 1)
    y = randint(0, len(actual_env[x]) - 1)
    actual_env[x][y] += 1

# Run A* and get a path
path = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4),
        (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]  # dummy path


def effective_slices(i_w, j_h):
    """Note: Depends on globals width and height."""
    w, h = width - 1, height - 1
    i_w_p, j_h_p = max(0, i_w - 1), max(0, j_h - 1)
    i_w_s, j_h_s = min(w, i_w + 1), min(h, j_h + 1)
    return slice(i_w_p, i_w_s), slice(j_h_p, j_h_s)


# Traverse path, checking for "new" obstacles
for step in path:
    x, y = step[0], step[1]
    # check area around agent
    dim_w, dim_h = effective_slices(x, y)
    actual_set = set(map(tuple, actual_env[dim_w][dim_h]))
    known_set = set(map(tuple, known_env[dim_w][dim_h]))
    sym_diff = actual_set.symmetric_difference(known_set)
    if sym_diff:  # internal map doesn't match real world, update
        for (i, j) in product(range(dim_w.start, dim_w.stop + 1), 
                              range(dim_h.start, dim_h.stop + 1)):
            if known_env[i][j] != actual_env[i][j]:
                known_env[i][j] = actual_env[i][j]
                # Re-run A*
```

(Edited): Added some kind of reuse of indexing above in eager update loop.

**2nd Edit** to accommodate for comment w.r.t. updated question (cf. comment below):

Looking at the amended question i.e. the snippet now relating to a `numpy` based implementation, I'd suggest two changes that would make the code clearer to me at least:

1. To avoid the literal `+ 1` clutter address the issue of slices excluding the `stop` by introducing *supreme* values for `right` and `bottom`
2. Define the section boundary box with `min`and `max` to make the relation clear.

Like so:

```
# ... 8< - - 
# check area around agent (note: uses numpy)
sight = 1
left, right_sup = max(0, x - sight), min(x + sight + 1, width)
top, bottom_sup = max(0, y - sight), min(y + sight + 1, height)

known_section = known_environment[left:right_sup, top:bottom_sup]
actual_section = actual_environment[left:right_sup, top:bottom_sup]
if not np.array_equal(known_section, actual_section):
    known_environment[left:right_sup, top:bottom_sup] = actual_section
# - - >8 ...
```

... or getting rid of *colon-itis* (sorry):

```
# ... 8< - - 
h_slice = slice(max(0, x - sight), min(x + sight + 1, width))
v_slice = slice(max(0, y - sight), min(y + sight + 1, height))

known_section = known_environment[h_slice, v_slice]
actual_section = actual_environment[h_slice, v_slice]
if not np.array_equal(known_section, actual_section):
    known_environment[h_slice, v_slice] = actual_section
# - - >8 ...
```

Should be concise read, easy on the run time and nice playground.

... but image processing (e.g. with fixed masks) and staggered grid processing algorithms should be abound to offer ready made solutions

Comment: I was playing with using numpy slicing, and array_equal instead of sets. This way we avoid having to create sets. What I have now (see edit) is looking similar to your solution, though I find your use of max to be more elegant than my if-thens.

Comment: In my folklore ;-) when repeatedly using the same slice, it is better readable to introduce a clear token for the repeated occurrences of the one thing (and not literal that a parser/reader has to combine) and second, you can ask the slice questions, like `a_slice.start`, `a_slice.stop`, etc and it is more versatile, as you can create it dynamically via a clear function syntax (like range) ... if this is better optimizable - I currently do not know, but I would suggest so (maybe try the dis module or ...). Does this illustrate my personal view on the difference sufficiently?