# Fastest way to compare Array-of-array?

Tags: python, arrays, comparison, arrayofarrays

I have array-of-arrays like the ones below :

```
[[0, 3], [0, 4, 1, 5], [0, 2]]
[[0, 4, 1, 5], [0, 3], [0, 2]]
[[0, 2], [0, 4, 1, 5], [0, 3]]

[[0, 4, 1, 5, 3], [0, 2]]
[[0, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2]]
```

If you look at the first 3 examples they are the same array, just ordered differently.

At any time I have to compare two such AoA and figure out if they are the same.

What is the fastest way to do that ?
The arrays themselves are small, but I have to do this check very often.

Comment: Heavily related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105777/how-to-compare-a-list-of-lists-sets-in-python

Comment: Those are not arrays, those look like lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the sub-lists to tuples(immutable) using `map(tuple,list))` + sort the main list (which sorts the tuples based on the integer element ordering).

```
l1 = [[0, 3], [0, 4, 1, 5], [0, 2]]
l2 = [[0, 4, 1, 5], [0, 3], [0, 2]]
l3 = [[0, 2], [0, 4, 1, 5], [0, 3]]
print (sorted(map(tuple,l1)) == sorted(map(tuple,l2)))
#True
print(sorted(map(tuple,l2)) == sorted(map(tuple,l3)))
#True
print (sorted(map(tuple,l3)) == sorted(map(tuple,l1)))
#True

l4 = [[0, 4, 1, 5, 3], [0, 2]]
l5 = [[0, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2]]
sorted(map(tuple,l4)) == sorted(map(tuple,l5))
#False
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to flatten the two arrays and compare. Like this:

list1 = [[0, 3], [0, 4, 1, 5], [0, 2]]

list2 = [[0, 4, 1, 5], [0, 3], [0, 2]]

def flat(ls):
    return [val for sublist in ls for val in sublist]

set(flat(list1)) == set(flat(list2))