# How to compare list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison

I have 2 lists like the following:

```
a=[[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0]]
b=[[1,0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,0]]
```

I want to return true if all the sublists in b are present in a and vice versa.
That means a should be equal to b but indexes of the sublists can be different.
eg:

```
a=[[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0]]
b=[[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0]]
```

Above a and b are equal and comparison should return true. Also, the sublists will only contain a combination of 1s or 0s. How do I compare them?
I tried converting them to sets : set(a) but this is throwing an error.
Apart from that, when I tried the following code in a while loop, it gave an error

```
a=[[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0]]
b=[[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0]]

def sublists_equal(a, b):
    return all(l for l in b if l in a)

print(sublists_equal(a, b))
```

The error was:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried printing both the arrays to see what the problem was, they are printing like follows:

```
[[0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0]]
[array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare a list of lists/sets in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105777/how-to-compare-a-list-of-lists-sets-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `all()` built-in function to check whether all sub-lists `l` of `b` can be found in `a`.

```
a=[[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0]]
b=[[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0]]

def sublists_equal(a, b):
    return all(l for l in b if l in a)

print(sublists_equal(a, b))
```

Should you wanted to use sets, you would have to convert each sub-list to a tuple, which is a hashable type, and then compare their symmetric difference denoted by the `^` operator which returns the set of elements not found in both lists. If the symmetric difference is the empty `set()`, which is negated to `True` using the `not` operator, then the lists have equal sub-lists.

```
def sublist_equal2(a, b):
    return not set([tuple(l) for l in a]) ^ set([tuple(l) for l in b])

print(sublist_equal2(a, b))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Your solution works independently but I am trying to use it in a while loop and it is throwing an error, I have edited the question, please take a look, thanks!

Comment: @hahahj That happens because an numpy array is different than a list.
You didn't specify that you were using numpy which is an external library.
Nonetheless, you can still use my function as such: `sublists_equal(a.tolist(), b.tolist())`

Comment: If this line doesn't work, edit the while loop segment in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to sort the lists before comparing them:

```
def compare_lists(a, b):
    return sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```

this handles cases where there are duplicate values.

If duplicates don't matter, and the sublists only contains 1 and 0, you could convert them to integers:

```
def sublists_to_integers(lst):
    return [int(''.join(str(i) for i in item), 2) for item in lst]

def compare_lists(a, b):
    return set(sublists_to_integers(a)) == set(sublists_to_integers(b))
```

which depending on your list size might be faster and/or use less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this late response. I came across this topic in search of some suggestions about a similar problem. You can solve it by using (based on answer solid.py, but I am a newbie and cannot add comments yet):

```
a=[[1,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0]]
b=[[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0]]
c=[[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1]]

def sublists_equal(a, b):
    return all(l in a for l in b)

print(sublists_equal(a, b))
print(sublists_equal(a, c))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34921839)