# Excluding common element from list python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python, compute list difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference)

I have two lists
 For example:

```
A = [1,3,5,7]
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Now, A is always a subset of B
I want to generate a third list C:
which has elements which are present in B but absent in A
like

```
C = [2,4..]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C = sorted(list(set(B) - set(A)))
```

That should do it.

Comment: No need for the `list`. `sorted` always produces a list.

Answer (score 4):

[List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are one way to do this:

```
[x for x in B if x not in A]
```

If you use Python, I recommend gaining familiarity with list comprehensions. They're a very powerful tool.

(Several people have suggested using `set`. While this is a very good idea if you only care about whether or not an element is in the set, note that it will not preserve the order of the elements; a list comprehension will.)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> set(B) - set(A)
set([8, 2, 4, 6])
```

or

```
>>> sorted(set(B) - set(A))
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do this is

```
C = [x for x in B if x not in A]
```

This will become slow for big lists, so it would be better to use a `set` for `A`:

```
A = set(A)
C = [x for x in B if x not in A]
```

If you have multiple operations like this, using sets all the time might be the best option.  If `A` and `B` are sets, you can simply do

```
C = B - A
```