# Why use a set for list comparisons?

Tags: python

I just read another users question while looking for a way to compute the differences in two lists.

[Python, compute list difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference)

My question is why would I do

```
def diff(a,b):
    b = set(b)
    return [aa for aa in a if aa not in b]
```

rather than doing

```
def diff(a,b):
    tmp = []
    for i in a:
        if(i not in b):
            tmp.append(i)
return tmp
```

edit: just noticed the second diff function actually returned the similarities.  It should be correct now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just from an algorithmic perspective, it takes `O(n)` to construct the set and `O(n)` to do the list comprehension (since testing if an element is contained in a set is `O(1)`). However in the second example, it would take `O(n^2)` to loop through both lists. So regardless of the programming language, the first approach is superior.

Also, list comprehensions in python are inherently faster than a for loop. This reduces the constant factor even more (and significantly so too). The reason why can be summarized in [this post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-May/1243754.html) which I quote here:

> The fact that list comprehensions can only be comprised of
>   expressions, not statements, is a considerable factor, as much less
>   work is required behind the scenes for each iteration.  Another factor
>   is that the underlying iteration mechanism for list comprehensions is
>   much closer to a C loop than execution of a for loop.

Comment: Good explanation of why the latter is O(n^2). Also, here's some `timeit` timings I did on the list comprehension vs for loop approach (list comprehensions are about twice as fast in my example): https://gist.github.com/2647005

Comment: wow... that is some upsetting evidence.  I'm implementing the first one for sure.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference between the two options is that the one that uses `set` is asymptotically much more efficient.

Under reasonably favourable conditions, looking up an item in a set can be done in `O(1)` time; looking up an item in a list requires `O(n)` time.

The second, less significant, difference is that one version uses a list comprehension while the other uses a `for` loop. List comprehensions tend to produce more compact code. They also tend to be more efficient (although if performance is a concern, the only way to get an accurate picture is by running benchmarks).

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension is generally regarded as more efficient than using regular list operations when creating a list. If memory is a concern, you may want to use a generator instead.

[This](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops) provides a bit of information re performances of `for`-loops, `map` and `list comprehension`. @benhoyt also provided a useful [link](https://gist.github.com/2647005) comparing loops vs list comprehension.

However, please note that if performance is a specific concern, it might be worth your while to time/benchmark your various options to select the best option for your specific requirements.

Comment: How much faster is a list comprehension in this instance?

Comment: A list comprehension might be *slightly* faster than building a list with append, but not much. The real gain of sets over lists here is that `elem in container` is O(len(container)) if `container` is a list, but O(1) if `container` is a set.

Comment: @Gabe I added a link to my post that talks about for-loops vs map vs list comprehensions that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using the set is usually faster because it only has to iterate `b` once, while your example has to iterate `b` once for each element in `a`.

Answer (score 2):

I've done some tests:

test_lists.py

```
a = range(1, 1000)
b = range(2, 1002)

tmp = []
for i in a:
    if(i not in b):
        tmp.append(i)
```

test_set_list_comprehensions.py

```
a = range(1, 1000)
b = range(2, 1002)

b = set(b)
[aa for aa in a if aa not in b]
```

test_set.py

```
a = range(1, 1000)
b = range(2, 1002)
list(set(a).difference(set(b)))
```

And that's what timeit says:

```
~$ python -m timeit 'import test_lists'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.671 usec per loop
~$ python -m timeit 'import test_set_list_comprehension'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.766 usec per loop
~$ python -m timeit 'import test_set'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.656 usec per loop
```

So the best one seems to be:

test_set.py

```
a = range(1, 1000)
b = range(2, 1002)
list(set(a).difference(set(b)))
```