# What is the most efficient way to remove a group of indices from a list of numbers in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, list, indexing

So I was wondering how I can, using Python 2.7, most efficiently take a list of values used to represent indices like this: (but with a length of up to 250,000+)

```
indices = [2, 4, 5]
```

and remove that list of indices from a larger list like this: (3,000,000+ items)

```
numbers = [2, 6, 12, 20, 24, 40, 42, 51]
```

to get a result like this:

```
[2, 6, 20, 42, 51]
```

I'm looking for an efficient solution more than anything else. I know there are many ways to do this, however that's not my problem. Efficiency is. Also, this operation will have to be done many times and the lists will both get exponentially smaller. I do not have an equation to represent how much smaller they will get over time.

edit:

Numbers must remain sorted in a list the entire time or return to being sorted after the indices have been removed. The list called indices can either be sorted or not sorted. It doesn't even have to be in a list.

Comment: What are you trying to remove?

Comment: Do you want to alter the list in place or create a new list or doesn't matter?

Comment: See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference

Comment: @voscausa: that's removing elements by value, not by index

Comment: @enginefree Each item in the list called indices represents an index in the list below it called numbers. So I'm trying to remove numbers[2] numbers[4] and numbers[5] from numbers.

Comment: @FogleBird It doesn't matter. As long as it's efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a suspicion that taking whole slices between the indices might be faster than the list comprehension

```
def remove_indices(numbers, indices):
    result = []
    i=0
    for j in sorted(indices):
        result += numbers[i:j]
        i = j+1
    result += numbers[i:]
    return result
```

Comment: Good point actually. Also, is the sorted() method necessary in the for loop? indices is already sorted. I haven't used python in a while so maybe I'm not getting something.

Comment: Also, I'm about to test it.

Comment: Much faster... 0.15 seconds.

Comment: I sorta considered this too but was too lazy to try it. Well done!

Comment: @StevenHicken, You don't need the `sorted()` if indices is always already sorted. It won't hurt much to leave it in though because timsort is linear over a presorted list.

Comment: This is a good amount faster than FogleBird's solution. I couldn't seem to get his improved function to work but his original took 1.05 seconds and yours took 0.75 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: @StevenHicken: My improved one assumed that indices was already a set.

Comment: In any case, gnibbler's is still faster.

Comment: I added a graph with benchmarks of different options, this is by far the best.

Comment: @FogleBird That'd make a lot more sense. No wonder I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to consider using the [numpy](https://numpy.org/) library for efficiency (which if you're dealing with lists of integers may not be a bad idea anyway):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([2, 6, 12, 20, 24, 40, 42, 51])
>>> np.delete(a, [2,4,5])
array([ 2,  6, 20, 42, 51])
```

Notes on `np.delete`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

It might also be worth at looking at keeping the main array as is, but maintaining a masked array (haven't done any speed tests on that either though...)

Comment: I tested this using my test suite in my answer and it's not significantly faster than a list comprehension. (0.53 seconds versus 0.59 seconds)

Comment: Last time I tried installing numpy, I couldn't find a 64-bit build for Mac OS X Lion. Only 32-bit. And I would really prefer to use 64-bit. I could be wrong though. They may have a 64-bit build that I haven't seen.

Comment: @StevenHicken might also be worth looking at masked arrays

Comment: I just took a look at masked arrays. They may come in use but I would have to redesign the algorithm I'm working on.

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
>>> numbers = [2, 6, 12, 20, 24, 40, 42, 51]
>>> indicies = [2, 4, 5]
>>> offset = 0
>>> for i in indicies:
...     del numbers[i - offset]
...     offset += 1
...
>>> numbers
[2, 6, 20, 42, 51]
```

**Edit:**

So after being hopelessly wrong on this answer, I benchmarked each of the different approaches:

[image]

Horizontal axis is number of items, vertical is time in seconds.

The fastest option is using slicing to build a new list (from @gnibbler):

```
def using_slices(numbers, indices):
    result = []
    i = 0
    for j in indices:
        result += numbers[i:j]
        i = j + 1
    result += numbers[i:]
```

Surprisingly it and "sets" (@Eric) beat `numpy.delete` (@Jon Clements)

Here's [the script I used](https://gist.github.com/4151954), perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: Consider that each `del` operation is resizing the list.

Comment: @JonClements, interestingly masked array seem to perform poorly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my first approach.

```
def remove_indices(numbers, indices):
    indices = set(indices)
    return [x for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if i not in indices]
```

Here's a test module to test it under the conditions you specified. (3 million elements with 250k to remove)

```
import random

def create_test_set():
    numbers = range(3000000)
    indices = random.sample(range(3000000), 250000)
    return numbers, indices

def remove_indices(numbers, indices):
    indices = set(indices)
    return [x for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if i not in indices]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    numbers, indices = create_test_set()
    a = time.time()
    numbers = remove_indices(numbers, indices)
    b = time.time()
    print b - a, len(numbers)
```

It takes around 0.6 seconds on my laptop. You might consider making the indices a set beforehand if you'll be using it multiple times.

(FWIW bradley.ayers solution took longer than I was willing to wait.)

**Edit**: This is slightly faster: (0.55 seconds)

```
def remove_indices(numbers, indices):
    return [numbers[i] for i in xrange(len(numbers)) if i not in indices]
```

Comment: Thanks for testing all of those. As of right now, this seems like the best route to go.

Comment: I'm going to wait for a little while to see if another solution shows up.

Comment: Can you try out my answer on your laptop?

Answer (score 2):

Not that efficient, but a different approach

```
indices = set([2, 4, 5])

result = [x for i,x in enumerate(numbers) if i not in indices]
```

Comment: This is how I would do it. It has the added benefit of not requiring an external dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Another different approach to achieve that:

```
>>> numbers = [2, 6, 12, 20, 24, 40, 42, 51]
>>> indices = [2, 4, 5]
>>> [item for item in numbers if numbers.index(item) not in indices]
[2, 6, 20, 42, 51]
```