# find uncommon rows between two csv files having common field

Tags: python, pandas

I have one csv file with following data

```
code
AAA
BBA
CCC
```

and another csv file with different structure but common column:

```
code
AAA
BBA
CCF
```

I want to find what code in first does not exist in the second dataframe. In this case CCC.

How can i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `pandas` tag, I will assume you are after a solution involving `pandas`. If you had read both CSV files in two different dataframes, then assuming that the first CSV is read in `df_1` and the second one in `df_2`, you could do this:

```
>> df_1[~df_1['code'].isin(df_2['code'])][['code']]
```

or

```
>> set(df_1['code'].values.tolist()) - set(df_2['code'].values.tolist())
```

or

```
>> set(list(df_1['code'])) - set(list(df_2['code']))
```

I hope this helps!