# finding different words in two lists

Tags: python

i have two list and i want to delete the matching one and keep the different.
here is the code:

```
def check_synonym(text):
     tokens=regexp_tokenize(text, r'[،؟!.؛\s+]\s*', gaps=True)
     based_text= ' '.join(cursor.execute('SELECT request FROM Male_Conversation_Engine WHERE request REGEXP?',[tokens[0]]).fetchone())
     based_tokens=regexp_tokenize(str(based_text), r'[،؟!.؛\s+]\s*', gaps=True)
    for w1 in based_tokens:
       for w2 in tokens:
           if w1 == w2:
              based_tokens.remove(w1),tokens.remove(w2)      
return list
```

if the two list are "in Arabic":

```
 tokens = ['هذا','الجهاز','الجميل']
 based_tokens = ['هذا','الجهاز','جيد']
```

the Output should be:

```
 tokens = ['الجميل']
 based_tokens = ['جيد']
```

the actual Output:

```
 tokens = ['الجهاز','جميل']
 based_tokens = ['الجهاز','جيد']
```

the side only delete the first element 'هذا' and return the rest of the list.

(using python3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, compute list difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of sets and list comprehensions

```
s1 = set(tokens)
s2 = set(based_tokens)

tokens = [t for t in tokens if t not in s2]
based_tokes = [t for t in based_tokens if t not in s1]
```

The only reason I am using sets is because for large lists it is much faster to check membership with sets.

Comment: Once you convert them to `set`, you can also do `s1.difference(s2)`

Comment: @xbonez I don't like that solution for this problem because the second list could be five of the same thing that does not appear in the first list.

Comment: @xbonez it also kills the ordering of the lists, if that's important

Answer (score 0):

```
    set1=set(tokens)
    set2=set(based_tokens)

    tokens = set1-set2 
    based_tokens = set2-set1
```