# Using list comprehension to get a list of entries not in another list, preserving order and quantity

Tags: python, python-3.5

So I have a list, let's say

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4]
```

1 appears twice, 2 appears three times, 4 appears twice. Now I define

```
b = [4, 2, 2]
```

Now I want a new list, c, that has the entries of a that are not in b. I tried using list comprehension:

```
c = [x for x in a if x not in b]
```

However, this omits the entry if it is in b, rather than seeing how many of each entry are in b and removing that many from a.

```
c == [1, 3, 1]
```

I would want it to be

```
c == [1, 3, 1, 2, 4]
```

Can anyone provide some help?

Comment: This definetely can help, see difflib http://stackoverflow.com/a/15646006/7086023

Answer (score 4):

You can loop through list `b` and remove each element from list `a`:

```
for i in b:
    a.remove(i)

a
# [1, 3, 1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you! Asking the question made me think about this route and I came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Nice & simple answer! One thing of note is the O(n*m) complexity, which can be reduced to O(n + m) but not with such a clear, concise implementation. To do that you'd probably want to use a histogram via `collections.Counter`.