# Remove all of specific words in a list

Tags: python

I have a list like this `['land_transport', 'and', 'or', 'port', 'of', 'surveyor', 'and', 'organization']`. I want to remove all of the words: `and`, `or`, `of`. I, therefore, come up with the following block of code

```
my_list = ['land_transport', 'and', 'or', 'port', 'of', 'surveyor', 'and', 'organization']
print('Before: {}'.format(my_list))
my_list = list(filter(lambda a: 'and' not in a and 'of' not in a and 'or' not in a, my_list))
print('After: {}'.format(my_list))
```

However, my code gives the output like this

```
Before: ['land_transport', 'and', 'or', 'port', 'of', 'surveyor', 'and', 'organization']
After: []
```

What I want should be

```
['land_transport', 'port', 'surveyor', 'organization']
```

There are, of course, several ways to go around. But I want to insist on using lambda function to solve this problem. Any suggestions for my problem?

Comment: Your `'and' not in a` check is doing exactly what it says on the tin—finding any words that don't contain `and`. Since `land_transport` contains `and`, it gets filtered out. Presumably you're using `not in` instead of just `!=` for a reason, but without knowing what that reason is, it's hard to tell you how to fix things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, compute list difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filtering is not correct use:

```
filter_set = {'and', 'or', 'of'}
my_list = list(filter(lambda a: a not in filter_set, my_list))
```

You want all the items in `my_list` that are not in the `filter_set`, notice the use of a `set`, it will make the lookup much faster `(O(N) vs O(1))`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially the part **the use of a set**. Could you refer to any documents for this point, in your answer, @Netwave?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new list storing all of the words to be filtered:

```
my_list = ['land_transport', 'and', 'or', 'port', 'of', 'surveyor', 'and', 'organization']
to_remove = ['or', 'of', 'and']
new_list = list(filter(lambda x:x not in to_remove, my_list))
```

Output:

```
['land_transport', 'port', 'surveyor', 'organization']
```

Comment: Maybe filter/lambda instead of a list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

Although above answers serve the need, I think you intend to remove stop words.

`nltk` is best resource in Python for that. You can use [nltk.corpus.stopwords](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/)

You dont have to do much manipulation if you know you are removing the actual English stop words.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
word_list = ['land_transport', 'and', 'or', 'port', 'of', 'surveyor', 'and', 'organization']
filtered_words = [word for word in word_list if word not in stopwords.words('english')]

print(filtered_words)

['land_transport', 'port', 'surveyor', 'organization']
```

Vola