# How to return the difference of two multi-dimentional lists in Python?

Tags: python

How can I compare two multidimensional lists in python 2.6.6 and show the different elements.

I am trying to compare multidimensional list A with multidimensional list B and output the elements that are present in list A but not present in list B

```
aArray=[]
a1=[1],[2],[3]
a2=[1],[4],[5]

bArray=[]
b1=[1],[2],[3]
b2=[1],[6],[7]

aArray.append(a1)
aArray.append(a2)
aArray
[([1], [2], [3]), ([1], [4], [5])]

bArray.append(b1)
bArray.append(b2)
bArray
[([1], [2], [3]), ([1], [6], [7])]

aArray.difference(bArray)
```

Expected result:

```
([1],[4],[5])
```

actual result:

```
aArray.difference(bArray)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'difference'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, compute list difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference)

Comment: @YasinYousif Tanks for the reply, but that example is not a multidimensional list

Comment: Is there any reason you have lists of length one in the innermost level?

Comment: Also, can the nesting be arbitrarily deep, irregular and can `A` and `B` have unqequal numbers of elements?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple list comprehension will do:

```
a = [([1], [2], [3]), ([1], [4], [5])]
b = [([1], [2], [3]), ([1], [6], [7])]

print([x for x in a if x not in b])
[([1], [4], [5])]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `.difference` is a build in method for **sets** 
and does will not work for lists.

Hence,
 `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'difference'`

Just use of forloop to read the elemets in aArray and 
using **if** to print the

elements in aArary **and** not bArray using

`[diff for diff in aArray if diff not in bArray]`