# Finding all the neighbours of a given state

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

A state is a list of random integers from 0 - 4. Example = `[1, 0, 2, 3, 2]`. A neighbour is described as a change in one of the integers in the list. For example `[0, 0, 2, 3, 2]` is a neighbour of `[1, 0, 2, 3, 2]`. How would I find all possible neighbours of a given state?

Comment: Some kind of loop, I would guess.  What have you tried, and what's stopping you from proceeding?

Comment: If the difference between a state and its neighbour is exactly one integer, then you won't be able to list _all_ the neighbours since there will be infinitely many of them: `[2, 0, 2, 3, 2]`, `[3, 0, 2, 3, 2]` and so on would also be neighbours

Comment: This could be helpful: [compute list difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6486450/4518341). Order matters, right? Once you have the difference, you would just need to get its `len`.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood the question. I thought you would get two lists and have to determine if they're neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the total number of permutations for your sequence by using the formula `n^r` where `n` is the number of numbers you use and `r` is the number of elements in your sequence. In your case this would be `5^5`. [You can read more about this and see all the possible permutations here.](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html)

From the list you can create from what we've just calculated you can determine which of these permutations are neighbors and keep a count of each one you encounter. You can do this using a for loop `(for each permutation, check if it's a neighbor)`.

I have added a method I made called isNeighbor which returns true or false depending. Although this is in java the same prinicples I use also apply in python. I hope you are still be able to follow it with the comments I've supplied. If not I can try and explain further.

```
int[] cell = {1,0,2,3,1}; 
int[] cell = {0,0,2,3,1}; //example cells (stored as array of integers)

static boolean isNeighbor(int[] cell, int [] cell2)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < cell.length;i++) //for each number in array
            if(!(cell[i] == cell2[i])) //if the number at the same index isn't the same
                if(Math.abs(cell[i] - cell2[i]) != 1) //if the difference isn't 1
                    count+=2;
                else
                    count++;
        if(count > 1)
            return false; // is not a neighbor
        else
            return true; // is a neighbor
    }
```

If you need any clarification regarding this method or where to go from here feel free to ask! :)