# Compare two lists of strings and print non matches in Python?

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two lists:

```
listOne = ['John', 'James', Daniel', 'Peter', 'Luke']
listTwo = ['Daniel', 'Peter', Kate', 'Jenny']
```

I want to compare these two lists and return the non matches, and if need be, save this to another list, so the output should be:

```
Non-Matches: 'Kate', 'Jenny'
```

How can I achieve this? I looked at changing the lists to sets but have had no luck getting it working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, compute list difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference)

Comment: why 'James', 'John', 'Luke' are not in output ? they are also non match ?

Comment: I am having an issue as I am reading in the first list from a text file, the list is showing up as listOne = ["'John', 'James', Daniel', 'Peter', 'Luke'"] , it has speech marks at the start and end, will this effect comparison? it does not work

Answer (score 5):

you can use set , look at this function :

```
def list_diff(list1, list2):
    return (list(list(set(list1)-set(list2)) + list(set(list2)-set(list1))))
diff_values = list_diff(listOne, listTwo) # call to this function
```

python set : https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: I am having an issue as I am reading in the first list from a text file, the list is showing up as listOne = ["'John', 'James', Daniel', 'Peter', 'Luke'"] , it has speech marks at the start and end, will this effect comparison? it does not work

Comment: yes you have now list is len =1 of 1 item, try listOne = [l.replace("'",'') for l in listOne[0].split(',')] to make it a list of several items splited by comma

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to do that

```py
listOne = set(['John', 'James', 'Daniel', 'Peter', 'Luke'])
listTwo = set(['Daniel', 'Peter', 'Kate', 'Jenny'])
print(list(listTwo - listOne))
```

**Output**

```py
['Kate', 'Jenny']
```

Comment: I am having an issue as I am reading in the first list from a text file, the list is showing up as listOne = ["'John', 'James', Daniel', 'Peter', 'Luke'"] , it has speech marks at the start and end, will this effect comparison? it does not work