# Use list item index as index to another list in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have two lists:

```
A = ['PA', 'AT', 'TR']
removlistv = ['TR', 'AI', 'IO', 'SO', 'CR', 'PH', 'RT']
```

I find the intersection of the two lists:

```
rm_nodes = set(A) & set(removelistv)
```

Which creates the set `{'TR'}`. I now want to find the index of that intersection (or intersections) in the list `removelistv`:

```
indices = [removelistv.index(x) for x in rm_nodes]
```

So far so good, `indices` contains the correct value.
The problem starts when I want to use the index value (which in this case is `[0]` i.e. a list) to retrieve the matching item in a third list `removelistst = ['TR0', 'AI1', 'IO1', 'SO0', 'CR1', 'PH0', 'RT1']`. My goal is to remove the item `'TR0'` from `removelistst`. Basically, I want to remove items from this list based on the output of the intersection of the two lists in the beginning.

I've tried the following:

```
numbers =[ int(x) for x in indices ]
removelistst[numbers]
```

Which returns the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Are the elements in `removelistst` distinct?

Comment: Can't you just do `removelistst.remove(value + str(index))`?

Comment: @quamrana I just did, thanks

Comment: @Barmar Yes, they are

Comment: Why don't you calculate [the difference directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference)?

Comment: Isn't `indices` a list of numbers? Why do you need to create the `numbers` list?

Comment: @Barmar I thought this was a matter of extracting the list item from `indices` to reference the item in removelistst, because `removelistst[indices]` didn't work for me.

Comment: `numbers` will be the same as `indices`.

Comment: @Barmar, yeap I figured out later that it is the equivalent of `removelistst[indices]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through `indices` and pop the specified element out of `removelistst`.

```
for index in sorted(indices, reverse=True):
    removelistst.pop(index)
```

I sort `indices` in reverse so that removing an element won't affect the indexes of later elements to be removed.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out without sorting to observe the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of ways to do this, here's a list comprehension:

```
removelistst = [value for index, value in enumerate(removelistst) if index not in numbers]
```