# Removing a list from a existing list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I had a list called "list1" `list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]` and I had another list called "list2" `list2 = [1,2,3]` What would be the easiest way to take out 1,2,3 without using a loop to iterate through list2 then deleting them from list1?
Thanks!

Comment: Does the following answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/python-compute-list-difference

Comment: With `in` operator you can test if an item is in "list2" (but technically this is a hidden loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `set()` is for.

```
print(set(list1))
```

output

```
[1,2,3]
```