# How to remove elements from a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have two lists

```
first = ['-6.50', '-7.00', '-6.00', '-7.50', '-5.50', '-4.50', '-4.00', '-5.00'] 
second = ['-7.50', '-4.50', '-4.00']
```

I want to shorten `first` by every element that occur in `second` list.

```
for i in first:
    for j in second:
        if i == j:
            first.remove(i)
```

Don't know why this did not remove the `-4.00`

```
['-6.50', '-7.00', '-6.00', '-5.50', '-4.00', '-5.00']
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: A comparison of all the methods suggested in the answers below. http://codebunk.com/bunk#-ItP66mNZpNolwb3ZNX5

Comment: @spicavigo You'll need to run it on larger input to really see the difference. And move the setup lists out of the code too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> first = ['-6.50', '-7.00', '-6.00', '-7.50', '-5.50', '-4.50', '-4.00', '-5.00']
>>> second = ['-7.50', '-4.50', '-4.00']
>>> set_second = set(second) # the set is for fast O(1) amortized lookup
>>> [x for x in first if x not in set_second]
['-6.50', '-7.00', '-6.00', '-5.50', '-5.00']
```

Comment: Thank you, any idea my solution did not do it?

Comment: @nutship you shouldn't remove elements from a list while iterating through it :p http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python

Comment: @nutship what Haidro said ;)

Answer (score 2):

Don't modify sequences you are iterating through.

Shortest way to do this:

```
list(set(first) - set(second))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about order, use

```
list(set(temp1) - set(temp2))
```

References: [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, and you will see that the `-4.00`s don't come side by side.:

```
for i in first:
    for j in second:
        print i,j,
        if i == j:
            print 'removed'
            first.remove(i)
        else:
            print
```

- You shouldn't modify sequences you are iterating over.

TO solve your problem, just create a copy of your lists, which can be done by adding `[:]`:

```
for i in first[:]:
    for j in second[:]:
        if i == j:
            first.remove(i)
```

Another way to do this is:

```
[i for i in first if i not in second]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l3 = [x for x in first if x not in second]
```