# python creating a list from two other lists

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to write a function that takes in two lists, 
and for each item in the first list, looks into the second list, and  compares each 
item in the first list with each item in the second list. It needs to return a new list containing the all 
items that do not appear in first list.

So for instance, given a list:

```
list1 = ['yellow', 'blue', 'green']
```

and the second list:

```
list2 = ['orange', 'green', 'blue', 'pink', 'yellow']
```

it should return a list of only the items in list2 that are not in list1, like this:

```
['orange', 'pink']
```

I have written many functions but they keep returning duplicates, I really appreciate any help on this!

```
def different_colors(list1, list2):
    newlist = []
    for color in list1:
        newlist = [] 
        for color2 in list2:
            if color1 != color2:
                newlist.append(color2)
    return newlist
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists

Answer (score 3):

Use `set`s:

```
>>> set(list2) - set(list1)
{'orange', 'pink'}
```

Comment: To preserve the order: `s2 = set(list2); return [v for v in list1 if v not in s2]`

Answer (score 2):

Try using sets:

```
>>> list(set(list2) - set(list1))
['orange', 'pink']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python sets (http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
s1 = set(list1)
s2 = set(list2)
list(s2.difference(s1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little simpler than you think

```
newlist = []

for color in list2:
   if color not in list1:
        newlist.append(color2)

return newlist
```

converting `list1` to a set would make this more efficient