# Faster way to get the difference of two lists without set

Tags: python, performance, list, difference

I'm trying to compare two lists and get the new elements, including redundant elements.
For instance, the result of :

```
l1 = [1,2,3,3,4]
l2 = [3,3,3,4,4,5,6]
```

Is :

```
l2 - l1 = [3,4,5,6]
```

You can easily understand that I can't do it with set because

```
set(l1) = (1,2,3,4)
set(l2) = (3,4,5,6)
```

The result would be : (5,6)

I don't want to do it with an iteration such as

```
[i for i in l1 if i not in l2 ]
```

Because it's too slow (see benchmark at [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists))

Does anyone know how to do it without iteration and keep the redundant elements or iterative methods are the only way ?

Thanks !

**Benchmarking of the solutions :**

I benchmarked both of the given solutions and here's the result :

```
import random
init1 = list(range(10000))
init2 = [i*random.randint(1,50) for i in range(10000)]

# Put both solution in function, diff1 = remove method, diff2 = Counter method 

import time
tic1 = time.clock()
print(diff1(init2,init1))
toc1 = time.clock()
tic2 = time.clock()
print(diff2(init2,init1))
toc2 = time.clock()
print(toc1-tic1)
print(toc2-tic2)
```

And the results are :

```
2.756271607145601   for diff1
0.028116911506909315    for diff2
```

Comment: What's the problem with http://stackoverflow.com/a/3462202/1126943 ?

Comment: If `l1` and `l2` are guaranteed to be sorted, than this could be done in linear time like [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) in C++.

Comment: zch : The thing is that it's using sets and not keeping redundant values or it's too slow.
timrau : Yes they're sorted, I'll check it

Comment: also `[i for i in l1 if i not in l2 ]` is incorrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), that's exactly what [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is for:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list((Counter(l2) - Counter(l1)).elements())
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,3,4]
l2 = [3,3,3,4,4,5,6]

l3 = l1[:]
l4 = l2[:]

for item in l2:
    if item in l3:
        l3.remove(item)
        l4.remove(item)

>>> print l4
[3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: `list.remove` is an `O(N)` operation, so this is going to slow for large lists.

Comment: Besides, he does not want to use iterations. :-)