# python: find diff in pythonic way between list of values and list of model object i.e with models objects values

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, comparison

Wanted to get the difference between two list where `list1` is

```
 l1 = range(10003, 10011)
```

And `list2` i.e `list of database object` is`

```
 l2 = [<Model_obj: 10003 (3)>, <Model_obj: 10005 (5)>, <Model_obj: 10006 (6)>, <Model_obj: 10007 (7)>, <Model_obj: 10008 (8)>, <Model_obj: 10009 (9)>, <Model_obj: 10011 (11)>]
```

where `<Model_obj: 10003 (3)>` is having attributes like `number, name, id` etc. And `10003, 10005,... 10011` represents the values of `number` field of the model.

Now I want to get the list of values of missing numbers of second list i.e `list1` while comparing with first list i.e `list1`
so in this case **The Answer would be** `[10004, 10010]` because this two number is missing in `list2`

I can able to do this while creating a number list of `list2` using `for` loop and taking help of [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

I can achieve this by creating `list3` as

```
l3 = set([obj.number for obj in l2])
response = set(l1) - l3

**Output**
{10004, 10010}
```

But is this a pythonic way to do this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you have in your question is quite pythonic. If you wanted to use more list comprehension:

```
l1 = list(range(10003, 10011))
l2 = [<Model_obj: 10003 (3)>, <Model_obj: 10005 (5)>, <Model_obj: 10006 (6)>,
      <Model_obj:10007 (7)>, <Model_obj: 10008 (8)>, <Model_obj: 10009 (9)>,
      <Model_obj: 10011 (11)>]

nums_not_found = [val for val in l1 if val not in [obj.number for obj in l2]]
```

Comment: Thanks but this will never produce the expected result as `l2` will always have number presents in `l1` but reverse may not be true. let me update my question a bit but please analyze again this if you have time.

Comment: Thanks, This is another way to solve the problem but does not it cost more than using `set` as I mentioned in POST.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another efficient solution.  It uses iterators when possible (ie: `xrange`), and displays the list of missing IDs at the end.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

l1 = set( xrange(10003, 10011) )

l2 = [ dict(num=10003), dict(num=10008) ]

print 'Missing:', l1 - set( (obj['num'] for obj in l2) )
```

Example output:

```
Missing: set([10004, 10005, 10006, 10007, 10009, 10010])
```

Comment: Similar to this I already mentioned in POST. Thanks Anyway for your effort and time :)