# Fast way to find the difference between 2 lists that works in all cases

Tags: python, list, loops, set

I need to find the difference between two lists for a problem i am trying to solve.

For example if:

```
list1 = ["Johny", "Lisa", "Madison", "Kirean"]
list2 = ["Lisa", "Madison", "Kirean"]
print difference(list1, list2)
#Should return ["Johnny"]
```

I have tried two different methods.

One was looping through the list and checking for similar elements and removing similar elements. Which took too long to compile for half the cases.

The other way was using subtracting sets. But this approach returned nothing in some of the cases.(Those cases were solved by the first solution if they were within the time limit.)

Is there any other way that would be invincible and also fast enough?

This is the link to the problem: http://www.dmoj.ca/problem/coci14c2p2

And here is my code:

```
a = []
b = []
n = input()
for i in range(n):
    a.append(raw_input())
for i in range(n-1):
    b.append(raw_input())

print list(set(a) ^ set(b))[0]
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists

Comment: What do you want `difference(['a','b','c'], ['b','c','d'])` to return?  Do you want the symmetric difference (i.e ['a','d'])`?  Do you care about order?

Comment: "all cases" is a lot simpler if the items are all hashable (strings are of course)

Comment: @DSM It is guaranteed that all items in list2 are within list1

Comment: Now that's strange, because the only case I can think of in which subtracting sets should fail for you is if there are elements in `list2` you wanted to see which weren't in `list1`.  If all the elements of `list2` are in `list1`, there should be no difference between `set(list1) - set(list2)` and `set(list1) ^ set(list2)`.

Comment: The only thing I know about those cases is that they return nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set and `symmetric_difference()`, i.e. finding the elements that are in exactly one of the sets:

```
list1 = ["Johny", "Lisa", "Madison", "Kirean"]
list2 = ["Lisa", "Madison", "Kirean"]
list(set(list1).symmetric_difference(list2))
# Output: ['Johny']
```

Note that if `difference()` is used, the output will be empty if `list1` and `list2` are swapped.

Answer (score 2):

as @YS-L mentioned, `set.symmetric_difference` is what you need, but not `set.difference`. Also, you can use operator `^` instead:

```
In [108]: set(list2) ^ set(list1)
Out[108]: {'Johny'}

In [109]: set(list1).symmetric_difference(list2)
Out[109]: {'Johny'}
```

Comment: None of these solutions work for three of the test cases in the judge I am using.

Comment: @MehdiAlali then show others what in what cases it fails, and what's your expected input and output ;)

Comment: The problem is I have no idea what they are :(

Comment: then plz show the **original** problem on the judge and paste your code

Comment: I added it to the problem description

Answer (score 1):

you need to use set:

```
>>> list1 = ["Johny", "Lisa", "Madison", "Kirean"]
>>> list2 = ["Lisa", "Madison", "Kirean"]
>>> list(set(list1) - set(list2))
['Johny']
```

Comment: If order doesn't matter, this is a great way to do it.  You could also sort them and use something like the merge step of mergesort, especially if the sets are too big to fit into RAM.

Comment: @MehdiAlali update ur realtime output so we can understand better

Comment: If you do `list(set(list2)-set(list1))` you get an empty set.  `symmetric_difference` fixes it.  Just doing the difference returns everything in the first but not the second.  So if first is a subset of second, it returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)

result = list((set1 | set2) - (set1 & set2))
```