# getting the difference between lists, keeping non-unique values

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, difference

I am looking to get the difference between two lists.

I am looking for a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists) only I want to consider non-unique list values.

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2]

# i want
z = x - y
# z = [1, 2, 3]
```

The solution above my code turns the two lists into sets which allows the `-` operator to work on them but removes non unique values from the lists. Can you think of a simple 'one liner' solution that does what im looking for?

Comment: More information is required. What is the desired output for x = [1, 1, 1, 2], y=[1]? What is the desired output for x = [1], y=[2]?

Comment: see above, im looking to just return the difference, or the leftovers from x - y, im not too worried about x or y afterwards

Comment: _"im not too worried about x or y afterwards."_ I don't understand. I didn't say anything about preserving the original contents of the lists. Please just answer my questions.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the order of the values in list `x` in the result?

Comment: `x=[1,1,1,2], y=[1]` = `[1,1,2]`, just removes the one `1`, for `x=[1], y=[2]` = `[1]`, `2` is not removed as its not in the `x` list. that wont be a case in the code as `y` will always have elements of `x`. preservation of order is not important

Answer (score 1):

You could use `collections.Counter` to find the counts of elements in each list. Then you can take the difference and reconstruct a list from the results.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
>>> y = [1, 2]
>>> [k for _ in range(v) for k,v in (Counter(x) - Counter(y)).iteritems()]
[1, 2, 3]
```

The drawback being, the order of the result has no real correlation with the order of the input lists. The fact that the result shown above looks sorted is implementation-dependent and possibly only a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

might not be fancy, first thing that came to mind..

```
x=[1,1,2,2,3]
y=[1,2]

_ = [ x.remove(n) for n in y if n in x ]

x
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: Using a list comprehension simply for its side-effects (in order to create a "one-liner") is considered wasteful and basically a poor practice by many.

Comment: @martineu, could you explain your comment? for curiosity and learning, what is a 'list comprehension'?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2]
z = [n for n in y if (n in x) and x.remove(n)] + x
print(z)  # -> [1, 2, 3]

x = [1, 1, 1, 2]
y = [1]
z = [n for n in y if (n in x) and x.remove(n)] + x
print(z)  # -> [1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just described the union of two sets, so use `set`:

```
>>> list(set(x).union(set(y)))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I think he wants the difference, not the union. So x = [1,2,2] and y=[1] should have a result of [2,2].

Comment: What about `a=[1,4]` and `b=[5]`? `a-b=[1,4,5]`?

Comment: Not guaranteed to preserve order.

Comment: I might be reading this wrong, but from my understanding `x - y ` gives the inverse of the union, and he wants the inverse of _that_.