# Keep values of dataframe that are contained in an other dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe that contain lists and i want to keep the elements of the first dataframe that are contained in the second dataframe. Is it possible or i must try some other data structures?

example of input:

df1:

```
elem1
a,c,v,b,n
b
c,x,a
```

df2:

```
elem2
j,k,a,i,v
o,b
g,f,w
```

expected output:

```
elem
a,v
b
NaN
```

Comment: DataFrame.subtract()?

Comment: The kernel dies maybe because i have a lot of data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so first of all you can create a regular expression of letters you want to match

```
In [77]:
chars = df2.elem2.str.replace(',' , '|')
chars
Out[77]:
0    j|k|a|i|v
1          o|b
2        g|f|w
Name: elem2, dtype: object
```

the concatenate both into a data frame in order to perform a custom function later

```
In [24]:
to_compare = pd.concat([df1 , chars] , axis = 1)
to_compare
Out[24]:
       elem1    elem2
0   a,c,v,b,n   j|k|a|i|v
1   b           o|b
2   c,x,a       g|f|w
```

finally use your regular expression to match the date from `elem1`

```
In [76]:
to_compare.apply( lambda x : ','.join(re.findall(x['elem2'] , x['elem1'])) , axis = 1)
Out[76]:
0    a,v
1      b
2       
dtype: object
```

if you want to convert empty string from the final result to `NAN` , I'll leave you to figure it out on your own :-)

Comment: Thank you but i get an error at this line `to_compare.apply( lambda x : ','.join(re.findall(x['elem2'] , x['elem1'])) , axis = 1)` at re. why?

Comment: have you imported `regex` module `import re` ?

Comment: Is there any way to make it run with dataframes of different size?

Answer (score 1):

First columns are converted to lists by function [str.split](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

If `indexes` are same in both dataframes, you can easily add column from one `df` to another.

You can [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) difference of [sets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462160/2901002) converted from lists of columns and then convert to list. You have to use `axis=1`, because apply function to each row.

```
print df
#       elem1
#0  a,c,v,b,n
#1          b
#2      c,x,a
print df1
#       elem2
#0  j,k,a,i,v
#1        o,b
#2      g,f,w

#convert to lists
df['elem1list'] = df['elem1'].str.split(',')
df1['elem2list'] = df1['elem2'].str.split(',')

#add column from df1
df['elem2list']  = df1['elem2list'] 
print df
#       elem1        elem1list        elem2list
#0  a,c,v,b,n  [a, c, v, b, n]  [j, k, a, i, v]
#1          b              [b]           [o, b]
#2      c,x,a        [c, x, a]        [g, f, w]

df['elem'] = df.apply(lambda x:  list(set(x['elem2list']).intersection(x['elem1list'])), axis=1)
print df
#       elem1        elem1list        elem2list    elem
#0  a,c,v,b,n  [a, c, v, b, n]  [j, k, a, i, v]  [a, v]
#1          b              [b]           [o, b]     [b]
#2      c,x,a        [c, x, a]        [g, f, w]      []
```

Comment: `set(x['elem2list']).intersection(x['elem1list'])` is even more better at the last step

Comment: This  actually works for different size dataframes. Nice catch!