# How to XOR two strings in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

H, I'm trying to XOR two strings (which should become hex first) in Python.
I know one way will work:

```
def xor_two_str(str1, str2):
    return hex(int(str1,16) ^ int(str2,16))
```

But I tried sth like this:

```
def change_to_be_hex(str):
    return hex(int(str,base=16))
def xor_two_str(str1,str2):
    a = change_to_be_hex(str1)
    b = change_to_be_hex(str2)
    return hex(a ^ b)
print xor_two_str("12ef","abcd")
```

This will return TypeError: ^ shouldn't be used between str, str.
I don't know why.

And also this function won't work:

```
bcd = change_to_be_hex("12ef")
def increment_hex(hex_n):
   return hex_n + 1
result = increment_hex(bcd)
print result
```

The error message is : TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
I feel this is so strange:(

Thank you!

Comment: @n1c9 he means byte xor operator, not power operator

Comment: @n1c9 Umm... Yes, it is

Comment: i stand corrected!

Comment: So you know how to XOR numbers represented as hex strings and you know that you can't use `^` on strings. What's your question then?

Comment: OP, don't you want to XOR the numerical value of every character in string1 with the value of the character at the same position in string2? (modulo length to wrap around in case they're not the same length). Why bother with the hex conversion?

Comment: I agree with jDo, see my answer :) You should use `ord()` on every char to xor them.

Comment: Thank you guys, I thought hex() will return a hex in python. I didn't realize it returns a string. Sorry, new to Python.

Comment: A number is just a number. It can't possibly be in any base – decimal, hex, binary, whatever – until you turn it into a string.  It doesn't make sense to talk about a number being in hex - I suppose in a sense the storage in memory is binary, but even then it's not literal 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hi,
The following function is returning the result of `hex()` which [returns a string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex).

```
def change_to_be_hex(s):
    return hex(int(s,base=16))
```

You should use the `^` operator on integers.

```
def change_to_be_hex(s):
    return int(s,base=16)
    
def xor_two_str(str1,str2):
    a = change_to_be_hex(str1)
    b = change_to_be_hex(str2)
    return hex(a ^ b)
print(xor_two_str("12ef","abcd"))
```

I'm not sure though that's the result you're looking for. If you want to XOR two strings, it means you want to XOR each character of one string with the character of the other string. You should then XOR `ord()` value of each char or str1 with `ord()` value of each char of str2.

```
def xor_two_str(a,b):
    xored = []
    for i in range(max(len(a), len(b))):
        xored_value = ord(a[i%len(a)]) ^ ord(b[i%len(b)])
        xored.append(hex(xored_value)[2:])
    return ''.join(xored)
    
print(xor_two_str("12ef","abcd"))
```

Or in one line :

```
def xor_two_str(a,b):
    return ''.join([hex(ord(a[i%len(a)]) ^ ord(b[i%(len(b))]))[2:] for i in range(max(len(a), len(b)))])

print(xor_two_str("12ef","abcd"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`hex` returns a string, so you're trying to xor two strings.

```
def change_to_be_hex(s):
   return int(s,base=16)
```

Should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

when you initially return hex, like in `change_to_be_hex`, you explicitly convert it to `int`.  you need to do that throughout your code to add something to it - so, change `increment_hex` to:

```
return (int(hex_n) + 1)
```

Comment: ^ IS recognized, it's the bitwise xoring operation.

Comment: Have you tried `4 ^ 5`?  What do you know?  no error.  Not only is `^` recognized, it does something quite similar to what the OP wants.