# Python Array Substraction

Tags: python, arrays, string

I want to substract an array from another one which contains it. For example I have two arrays: array1 and array 2, where array2 is contained in array1.

```
array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
array2 = ["a", "b"]
```

And I want to do array1 - array2 which would be stored in a third array: array3

```
array3 = ["c", "d", "e"]
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sets for this `set(array1) - set(array2)`

Or, if you really wanted to do a list comprehension

```
array_3 = [x for x in array_1 if x not in array_2]
```

Comment: Thanks! Really helped me out

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` for that:

```
>>> array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> array2 = ["a", "b"]

>>> list(set(array1) - set(array2))
['c', 'e', 'd']
```