# Python way of doing difference of lists containing lists

Tags: python

Consider two lists A and B. I know that `list(set(A) - set(B))` will give the difference between A and B. What about the situation whereby elements in both A and B are lists. i.e. A and B are list of list? For e.g.

```
A = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
B = [[3,4], [7,8]]
```

I wish to return the difference `A - B`  as a list of list i.e. `[[1,2],[5,6]]`

```
list(set(A) - set(B))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Comment: `diff = [a for a in A if a not in B]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to convert the list of lists to lists of tuples,
which are hashable and are, thus, candidates of making sets themselves:

```
In [192]: C = set(map(tuple, A)) - set(map(tuple, B))

In [193]: C
Out[193]: {(1, 2), (5, 6)}
```

And one more touch:

```
In [196]: [*map(list, C)]
Out[196]: [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

**ADDED**

In python 2.7 the final touch is simpler:

```
map(list, C)
```

Comment: I think, you should reformat your answer in a way that OP needs. A `list of lists` rather than `a set of tuples` may be.

Comment: @IsraelUnterman It appears python 2.7 does not support the starred expression `[*map(list, C)]`

Comment: See my addition for python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner you could use:

```
diff = [x for x in A if x not in B]
```

Or if you want to use filter:

```
diff = list(filter(lambda x: x not in B, A))
```

Comment: I got this. `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. A and B are both list of lists

Comment: @DougKruger You probably have a variable actually named "list" somewhere in your program which is overriding the builtin list function! Look through your code and if you have a variable by the name "list", change that name to something else.

Comment: @DougKruger Or use the first version. But note there is probably a bug in your program if you have called something in your program "list".

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [i for i in A if i not in B]
[[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` A and B are lists of list.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error in both `python2` and `python3`, works fine . May be the error comes from some other portion of your program.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
B = [[3, 4], [7, 8]]

print[x for x in A if x not in B]
```