# Find the uncommon word between two lists?

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists such as this:

```
>>>first = ['hello', 'hey', 'hi', 'hey']
>>>second = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello']
```

I want a new list that contains the word that is not included in the second list. In this case:

```
odd_word = ['hey']
```

What is the quickest way of doing this? Thank you.

I tried using the method shown here: [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists), but it gives me a blank list.

```
>>> odd = list(set(first) - set(second))
>>> odd
[]
```

Comment: you mean the duplicate? because "hey" is in both lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> first = ['hello', 'hey', 'hi', 'hey']
>>> second = ['hey', 'hi', 'hello']
>>> odd_word = list((Counter(first) - Counter(second)).elements())
>>> print(odd_word)
['hey']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

```
odd_word = [s for s in first if s not in second]
```

This will give you duplicates if there are duplicate words in `first` that aren't in `second`.  If you don't want the duplicates, do this instead.

```
odd_word = list({s for s in first if s not in second})
```

Comment: I dont think this works to find duplicates. It uses `in`, so if theres 1 or if theres 100 instances of the string it returns true. It doesnt do any kind of counting.

Comment: I'm talking about duplicates in `first`, not duplicates in `second`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/XOCglf I get an empty list. I'd expect `['hey']`. I don't think it matters which way round, all the strings are in both lists at least once, so `in` is not a valid way to find dupes, or am I missing something?

Comment: Words appearing in `second` should not appear in the result as specified in the question.  I'm talking about words appearing more than once in `first` and not at all in `second`.

Comment: In the OP's example there are no strings that are in first but not in seconds, unless you are counting the number of times each string appears, I admit the question is ambiguous on this point. I gave an example where it doesn't appear to work correctly but anyway I won't to press the point.