# Failing to retrieve difference between two lists

Tags: python, list, difference

**Set-up**

I have two lists containing unique `ID`'s: `tl` and `yl`.

An `ID` looks like `'97678410'`.

`len(tl) = 185` and `len(yl) = 182`.

---

**Problem**

I need the difference between the two lists. That is, I want to obtain a list containing all `ID`'s which are in `tl` but not in `yl`.

I've considered the following answers,

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462160/7326714
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462202/7326714
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462164/7326714

but my code,

```
final = [id for id in tl if id not in yl]
```

yields a `final` which is a copy of `tl`.

I have checked, and there are `ID`'s both in `tl` as in `yl`.

See the two lists [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/030217a0c63c8ed96240975d421f0b1c).

```
tl = ['97682631', '97682633', '97684139', '97680023', '97680021', '97678410', '97675792', '97673883', '97673946', '97671417', '97664888', '97666272', '97667377', '97670240', '97664192', '97655130', '97655288', '97655289', '97655293', '97645033', '97645101', '97632355', '97633891', '97616084', '97608150', '97606844', '97602650', '97584169', '97595622', '97583025', '97577940', '97569579', '97570582', '97565137', '97540897', '97539337', '97518058', '97518763', '97512249', '97512252', '97493818', '97489271', '97489272', '97461011', '97459708', '97456572', '97456626', '97456632', '97453137', '97454483', '97454693', '97454892', '97450659', '97446162', '97446168', '97434415', '97436210', '97427637', '97427635', '97427632', '97425356', '97417309', '97404715', '97404716', '97404718', '97392000', '97392111', '97386620', '97383091', '97384274', '97384337', '97383090', '97383089', '97366670', '97361744', '97361698', '97361701', '97361702', '97361722', '97276849', '97272708', '97236813', '97223049', '97213666', '97174233', '97164586', '97141165', '97141170', '97145252', '97136643', '97130696', '97042669', '97036543', '97007304', '96915042', '96887981', '96883537', '96865568', '96818145', '96818147', '96776783', '96767917', '96747326', '96747763', '96735976', '96739100', '96712470', '96714575', '96695120', '96667787', '96561238', '96583133', '96558744', '96553823', '96528225', '96389164', '96377527', '96251693', '96269789', '96246548', '96171491', '96161689', '96153980', '96131831', '96131903', '96131956', '96131749', '96126777', '96101829', '95958417', '95914030', '95735741', '95656954', '95503961', '95501454', '95502625', '95474681', '95468325', '95472748', '95474209', '95440076', '95443633', '95408190', '95276367', '95222901', '95218637', '95218977', '95187313', '94948878', '94806104', '94306925', '94097967', '94018001', '94090391', '93860264', '93423007', '93206111', '92251067', '92480603', '91550754', '89421778', '89658137', '89123891', '88860045', '88903715', '88169920', '85395060', '83483635', '82819637', '81788095', '80286689', '76733816', '74983036', '75270743', '72079817', '69163539', '66080651', '62508733', '58272006', '58927395', '59487908', '59764478', '57909458', '51546448', '41278948']
yl = [97655130, 97645101, 97642334, 97642352, 97633891, 97636938, 97632355, 97616084, 97606844, 97608150, 97605869, 97602650, 97584169, 97595622, 97583025, 97577940, 97574727, 97569579, 97570582, 97566414, 97565137, 97540897, 97539337, 97518058, 97518763, 97512252, 97512249, 97493818, 97489271, 97489272, 97461011, 97459708, 97456572, 97456626, 97456632, 97453137, 97454483, 97454693, 97454892, 97446162, 97446168, 97450659, 97436210, 97434415, 97427632, 97427635, 97427637, 97425356, 97417309, 97404718, 97404715, 97404716, 97392000, 97392111, 97392693, 97386620, 97383091, 97384274, 97384337, 97383090, 97383089, 97366670, 97361698, 97361701, 97361702, 97361722, 97361744, 97362574, 97276849, 97272708, 97236813, 97223049, 97213666, 97205682, 97174233, 97164586, 97141165, 97141170, 97145252, 97136643, 97130696, 97129530, 97042669, 97036543, 97007304, 96915042, 96890889, 96890891, 96883537, 96865568, 96818147, 96818145, 96801213, 96776783, 96767917, 96747326, 96747763, 96735976, 96739100, 96712470, 96714575, 96704316, 96695120, 96583133, 96558744, 96561238, 96553823, 96528225, 96466854, 96389164, 96377527, 96306028, 96251693, 96269789, 96246548, 96171491, 96153980, 96161689, 96131956, 96126777, 96131749, 96131831, 96131903, 96101829, 95958417, 95914030, 95735741, 95656954, 95503961, 95501454, 95502625, 95474681, 95468325, 95472748, 95474209, 95440076, 95443633, 95408190, 95276367, 95222901, 95218637, 95218977, 95187313, 95192968, 94948878, 94806104, 94306925, 94170831, 94097967, 94018001, 94090391, 93423007, 93206111, 92480603, 92251067, 91550754, 89865094, 89421778, 89658137, 89123891, 88860045, 88903715, 88169920, 85395060, 83483635, 82819637, 81788095, 80260371, 80286689, 76733816, 74983036, 75270743, 72079817, 69163539, 66080651, 62508733, 59487908, 59764478, 58272006, 58927395, 51546448, 41278948]
```

I'm pretty sure it's a stupid thing, as the code works for a simple example.

How do I obtain a `final` containing all `ID`'s in `tl` which are not in `yl`?

Comment: the lists have diferent types.... convert them both to `int` or `str`, then your code should work..., try this `final = [id for id in map(str, tl) if id not in map(str, yl)]`

Comment: pffff. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tl = ['97682631', '97682633', '97684139', '97680023',........., '51546448', '41278948']
yl = [97655130, 97645101, 97642334, 97642352,.........., 51546448, 41278948]

tl_unique = set(tl) # to make sure your current list contain set of all unique values
yl_unique = set(yl)
```

above two lines are not necessary if you are sure about not having duplicate values otherwise duplicate values will also be compared

```
diff = [int(i) for i in tl_unique if int(i) not in yl_unique] # your element in yl is in integer and in tl it is string so I used int(i) to compare integer value of element in tl_unique

print(diff)
```

Comment: I checked your answer on a phone and it was just horrible. Maybe reduce your input data set a little, and turn your code comments into real text, that would make your answer look nicer.

Comment: oh.. never thought about mobile user.. on site there is no problem appears. also I have included that sets from original source which helps in case external link not available... however check the edit you suggested..

Comment: it's always better to have a concise answer. Now looks a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `set` data structure:

```
>>> t1 = [2, 3, 4, 6]
>>> y1 = [2, 5, 7, 3]
>>> t1 = set(t1)
>>> y1 = set(y1)
>>> t1.difference(y1)
{4, 6}
```

Comment: Yes but op has a string/int mix in his dataset

Comment: Python's set data structure can contain multiple data types, so it is not an issue. If, however, the strings represents numeric IDs and you want "123" to be identified as 123, then you need to convert them to int first using: t1 = list(map(int, t1))

Answer (score 1):

Using two slightly simplified lists for clarity (one with strings and one with integers):

```
tl = ['1', '2', '3']
yl = [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Convert all the strings in `tl` to integers to be able to match them to the integers in `yl`

```
tl = [int(num) for num in tl]
```

Convert both lists into sets using the `set()` factory function.

**NOTE**: this presumes, as you have mentioned, that the values in each list are unique. `set()` will deduplicate values, without warning.

```
tl = set(tl)
yl = set(yl)
```

Use the builtin set method `.difference()` to identify the values in the first set that are not in the second set.

```
final = tl.difference(yl)
```