# Comparing large files with grep or python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have two lists of urls and I want to know new string. Example:

```
listA.txt
string1
string2

listB.txt
string1
string3
```

Then I compare both lists, to know the new string in list B:

```
grep -w -f listA.txt -v listB.txt
```

or

```
cat listA.txt | grep -Fxvf - listB.txt
```

final result:

```
string3
```

The problem is that i have a millions of strings, so running the command consumes all the resources of my PC and collapses.

Is there any way to do this with python (which consumes fewer resources and is faster)

thanks

Comment: Do it in chunks maybe?

Comment: The [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) probably isn't the straw which breaks the camel's back here but still a minor inefficiency. Your first `grep` command avoids this; the second could be rephrased as `grep -Fxcf - listB.txt <listA.txt`

Comment: Why do you think Python will be more efficient? The strings will take up the memory they take up unless you can tell Python something you can't tell `grep` (like for example that the strings represent something which can be stored much more compactly in memory, like numbers or hashes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method creates a set from the first file (`listA`). The the only memory requirement is enough space to hold this set.  It then iterates through each url in the `listB.txt` file (very memory efficient).  If the url is not in this set, it writes it to a new file (also very memory efficient).

```
filename_1 = 'listA.txt'
filename_2 = 'listB.txt'
filename_3 = 'listC.txt'
with open(filename_1, 'r') as f1, open(filename_2, 'r') as f2, open(filename_3, 'w') as fout:
    s = set(val.strip() for val in f1.readlines())
    for row in f2:
        row = row.strip()
        if row not in s:
            fout.write(row + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks. This question may interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572807/debugging-lists-with-python

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficient memory, read the files in to two lists. Then convert the lists to sets ie `setA = set(listA)` then you can use the various operators available with Python sets to do whatever operations you like e.g. `setA - setB`

I've used it before and it's very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to follow the solution here:

[Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

But first, you will need to know how to load the file into a list, which is here:

[How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Good luck. So something like this:

```
with open('listA.txt') as a:
    listA = a.readlines()
a.close()
with open('listB.txt') as b:
    listB = b.readlines()
b.close()
diff = list(set(listB) - set(listA))

#One choice for printing
print '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, diff))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't fit even the smaller file into memory, Python is not going to help. The usual solution is to sort the inputs and use an algorithm which operates on just three entries at a time (it reads one entry from one file and one from the other, then based on their sort order decides which file to read from next. It needs to keep three of them in memory at any time to decide which branch to take in the code).

GNU `sort` will fall back to disk-based merge sort if it can't fit stuff into memory so it is basically restricted only by available temporary disk space.

```
#!/bin/sh
export LC_ALL=C # use trad POSIX sort order
t=$(mktemp -t listA.XXXXXXXX) || exit 123
trap 'rm -f $t' EXIT HUP INT
sort listA.txt >"$t"
sort listB.txt | comm -12 "$t" -
```

If the input files are already sorted, obviously `comm` is all you need.

Bash (and I guess probably also Zsh and `ksh`) offers process substitution like `comm <(sort listA.txt) <(sort listB.txt)` but I'm not sure if that's robust under memory exhaustion.

As I'm sure you have already discovered, if the files are radically different size, it makes sense to keep the smaller one in memory regardless of your approach (so switch the order of `listA.txt` and `listB.txt` if `listB.txt` is the smaller one, here and in your original `grep` command line; though I guess it will make less of a difference here).