# How to find missing elements in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a target list as

```
target_list = ['one', 'two', 'three','four', 'five']
```

And a output list as

```
output_list = ['two','three','four', 'five']
```

The `target_list` is fixed, while the `output_list` will change depending on the output of some function. I want to find which element will be missed in the `target_list` based on the observation from `output_list`.

As in the above example, the element `one` is missing. I also want to count the number of missing element. Could you help me to do it in python?

Comment: did you attempt to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
target_list=['one', 'two', 'three','four', 'five']
output_list=['two','three','four', 'five']

l = [x for x in target_list if x not in output_list]
print("Number of items missing: " + len(l))

for x in target_list:
    if x in l:
        print(x + " is missing")
    else:
        print(x + " is not missing")
```

Output

```
one is missing
two is not missing
three is not missing
four is not missing
five is not missing
```

Comment: Thanks. How to count the `one` is missing 1. The len only count the number of missing, not the number of missing in each element

Comment: @Jame you want output as `one is missing`?

Comment: Yes. The output is right. One requirement counts the number of missing in each element. For example, the one is 1 missing, two is zero....

Answer (score 5):

You are going to have to compare if each item of a list is contained in the other one; probably the most efficient iway to do this is to use sets() and extract their difference.

```
target_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
output_list = ['two','three','four', 'five']

print(set(target_list).difference(set(output_list)))
```

### output:

```
set(['one'])
```

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. Please up vote my question before it is closed

Answer (score 3):

You can find the missing elements by using Counter. Every missing element has its occurrence.

```
from collections import Counter
target_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
output_list = ['two','three','four', 'five']
Counter(target_list)-Counter(output_list)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'one': 1})
```