# Finding row in list - python

Tags: python, list, row

I'm comparing two list of the same structure, one with the full dataset, and one with a subset.list_a ist the full list and list_b ist the subset. The result should be a list_c with the rows which are different or not in list_b.

```
for row_a in file_a:
    for row_b in file_b:
        if row_a != row_b:
            file_c.append(row_a)
```

The if statement seams to be wrong as file_c has multiple times the values of file_a and file_b.

Comment: `for row_a in file_a:`, `if row_a not in file_b:`, `file_c.append(row_a)`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually Python has something like `set` data structure. Maybe it would be beneficial to use it in your case?

```
file_a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
file_b = ['b']
set(file_a).difference(file_b)
Out[4]: {'a', 'c'}
list(set(file_a).difference(file_b))
Out[5]: ['a', 'c']
```

Comment: Even possible with `set(file_a) - set(file_b)`

Comment: @fernandezcuesta True, I didn't use it because `difference` method can operate on iterable, not necessarily another set, but yes, that's an option, probably even more clear.

Answer (score 2):

For sure there are better ways to do the job, but the following should do:

```
file_c.extend((row for row in file_a if row not in file_b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something simple like this:

```
file_c = list(set(file_a) - set(file_b))
```

Should be fairly low overhead using builtins.  I suppose it may be the same as

```
list(set(file_a).difference(file_b))
```

from erhesto's answer.  I'm not sure if the builtin method is faster than the *sub* overload on list().

Okay, after testing this is what I've found out.  I set up two different files sub.py and dif.py

**Outputs:**

```
   swift@pennywise practice $ time python sub.py
[27, 17, 19, 31]

real    0m0.055s
user    0m0.044s
sys 0m0.008s
swift@pennywise practice $ time python dif.py
[17, 19, 27, 31]

real    0m0.056s
user    0m0.032s
sys 0m0.016s
```

**Body of the .py files:**

***sub.py:***

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding utf-8 -*-


def test():
    lsta = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 19, 27, 31,]
    lstb = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13,]

    lstc = list(set(lsta) - set(lstb))

    return lstc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(test())
```

***dif.py***

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding utf-8 -*-


def test():
    lsta = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 19, 27, 31,]
    lstb = [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13,]

    lstc = list(set(lsta).difference(lstb))

    return lstc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(test())
```

Edited because I realized an error - forgot to execute the programs!

The sub operator is substantially faster on the system than the set.difference  So, I would probably stick with the '-' over the set.difference...it's easier for me to read what's going on.

Source for the set() - set() functionality:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462160/9268051