# Pattern Matching between two lists - Python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

i have a bunch of zip files in a directory and would like to get notified if one of them is missing .

Example code:

```
a = ['pattern1.zip', 'pattern2.zip', 'pattern3.zip']
b = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(some_path):
    for i in files:
        if i.endswith(('pattern1.zip', 'pattern2.zip', 'pattern3.zip')):
            b.append(i)
```

Output: 
b = ['test-pattern1.zip', 'test-pattern2.zip', 'test-pattern3.zip']

would like to match the contents of 'b' with 'a' and check if any of the zip files are missing

Comment: `if any(i.endswith(x) for x in a)`

Comment: Make sets of `a` and `b` and look for the set difference.

Comment: is it always in the format `test-patternX.zip`?

Answer (score 3):

I would take a different approach:

```
patterns = {'pattern1.zip', 'pattern2.zip', 'pattern3.zip'}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(some_path):
    for f in files:
        for pattern in patterns:
            if f.endswith(pattern):
                patterns.remove(pattern)
                break

print('Missing patterns:', patterns)
```

Comment: Works like a charm , Thanks a lot

Comment: for some strange reason it stopped working . If i rename the file (pattern1.zip) to 'patter.zip' , it is not able to detect the change and if the file with 'pattern1.zip' is deleted it is not able to detect that the file is missing . Any thoughts ?   @Alex Hall

Comment: Also , if there are multiple subdirectories with similar files matching the patterns ,the script is not able to iterate over them

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, try to figure it out, and if you get stuck, ask a new question on SO with a [mcve] that demonstrates only one of these problems as precisely as possible. But my first thought is that you have multiple files ending with the same pattern in different subdirectories, and if the program sees at least one it will mark the pattern as not missing, even if others have been removed, renamed, or aren't in some of the subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the lists to sets and take their difference [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists):

```
files_that_should_be_present = ['pattern1.zip', 'pattern2.zip', 'pattern3.zip']
files_that_are_present = ['pattern1.zip', 'pattern2.zip']

files_missing = list(set(files_that_should_be_present) - set(files_that_are_present))
print(files_missing)
```

Outputs: `['pattern3.zip']`

Comment: The filenames don't match exactly, it's based on endswith.