# Python find elements of list 1 which are not in list 2 - simple code not working

Tags: python, list, comparison

There's only a single line of code, and I won't bother you with the data as it is quite large.

I have a list of all requirements for some software in `allRequirements` and a second list of those requirements for which a test case exists in `requirementWithCoverage`.

I want to generate a list of those requirements with no test case coverage.

Lots of websites and S.O questions give the answer as this :

```
notCovered = list(set(allRequirements) - set(requirementWithCoverage))
```

However:

`len(set(allRequirements))` is 779 and
`len(set(requirementWithCoverage))` is 201, ***BUT***
`len(set(notCovered))` is 650

Obviously, I am making a very basic mistake - but for the life of me I can't see it. What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: Can you try symmetric_difference as in the answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists

Comment: Could you please confirm, that sets of the lists `requirementsWithCoverage` and `notCovered` are subsets of `allRequirements` by using `set(requirementsWithCoverage).issubset(set(allRequirements))` and `set(notCovered).issubset(set(allRequirements))`. My guess is there is something wrong with the coverage list.

Comment: the latter is True, but the former is False. That should be enough for me to debug it. If you can phrase that as an answer, please do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you observe is due to the fact that `requirementWithCoverage` contains elements that are not in `allRequirements`. Here is an example:

```
allRequirements         = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
requirementWithCoverage = [1,                7,           11, 12] # 11 and 12 are unexpectedly there
notCovered              = list(set(allRequirements) - set(requirementWithCoverage))

print(len(allRequirements))          # 10
print(len(requirementWithCoverage))  #  4
print(len(notCovered))               #  8 (6 was expected)
```

You can confirm this by printing the returned value of `set(requirementWithCoverage).issubset(set(allRequirements))` which should be False, whereas you expected it to be True.
And even better, you can print the unexpected elements of `requirementWithCoverage` through:

```
print(set(requirementWithCoverage) - set(allRequirements))
```